# Having a Print Statement Disappear after a Time Limit

Tags: python, csv, time, time-limiting

I would like to know if it is possible to limit the amount of time a print statement appears in the user console. I have a project that is a Contact Manager and it used a CSV file to store the contact data. The program is designed to create a new CSV file in the even that one is not available in the directory. If I run the program without the CSV file in the directory I have the console display a message to the user letting them know that a new file was created. I would like to have this message only display for maybe 10 seconds or so then disappear from the console. Is this possible? If so I would appreciate some suggestions. Below is the portion of the code that checks for the CSV file then creates a new one and notifies the user if a new one has been created.

```
    def read_contacts():
        try:
           contacts = []
           with open(FILENAME, newline="") as file:
                reader = csv.reader(file)
                for row in reader:
                    contacts.append(row)
           return contacts
        except FileNotFoundError:
           print("Could not find " + FILENAME + " file!\n + "Starting new contacts file...\n")
```

At this point the code continues to create a new CSV file. What I would like to do is have the previous print statement disappear after 10 seconds so that it doesn't display in the console the entire time the program is running.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the carriage return ("\r") to go back to the beginning of the printed line, wait for 10 seconds, and then replace the text.

Example:

```
import time
def read_contacts():
    try:
        contacts = []
        with open(FILENAME, newline="") as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                contacts.append(row)
        return contacts
    except FileNotFoundError:
        msg = "Could not find " + FILENAME + " file! Starting new contacts file..."
        print(msg, end="\r")
        time.sleep(10)
        print(" " * len(msg), end="\r")
```

Comment: Thank You for your input. I tried this way but in may case it just gives a 10 second delay after printing the 'msg' prior to starting the actual program.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not on windows, you can look into [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses%20curses). There is also a port for windows called [unicurses](https://pypi.org/project/UniCurses/).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative approach can be using the **\033[F** character:
(Since you do not want the delay to interrupt the remaining script, take advantage of python **threading** library)

```
import sys
import time
import threading

def func():
    time.sleep(10)
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F")

def read_contacts():
    try:
       contacts = []
       with open(FILENAME, newline="") as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                contacts.append(row)
       return contacts
    except FileNotFoundError:
       errmsg="Could not find " + FILENAME + " file!\n + "Starting new contacts file...\n"
       print(errmsg)
       t = threading.Thread(target=func)
       t.start()
       #remaining code
```

Comment: Thank You, in my case this gives a 10 second delay prior to starting the remainder of the program. The message still displays after that.

Comment: I have modified my answer according to your requirement. Give this a try. **Note: I have assumed you don't have any prints after the line `print(errmsg)`**.

Comment: Thank You for the update, I may be still doing something wrong or missing something because I changed my code to what you have provided and I am not getting a change in the function. It still works like before with the error message coming up and staying for the entirety of the program.

Comment: \033[F is unable to remove '\n' characters. Got this after some trial and error. Hence in your case, try using `print("\033[3A\033[K")` instead of `sys.stdout.write("\033[F")`. Also, if you are using python3.x, have a look at this one using curses: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420/python-rewrite-multiple-lines-in-the-console

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to use `sys` module.

```
import sys
import time

FILENAME = "build_local.sh"


def disappear(msg: str, seconds: int = 3):
    # Multiple lines cannot be flushed from screen without leaving empty gaps
    msg = msg.replace('\n', '\t').strip()
    sys.stdout.write(f"\r{msg}")
    time.sleep(seconds)
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    # Don't use print after flush as it will make future messages print on top of previous
    sys.stdout.write("\rTimed wait is done")


def read_contacts():
    try:
        contacts = []
        with open(FILENAME, newline="") as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                contacts.append(row)
        return contacts
    except FileNotFoundError:
        disappear(msg=f"Could not find {FILENAME} file!\nStarting new contacts file...")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_contacts()
```