# I have three progress bars and I need to display progress bars in each line

Tags: python, progress-bar

I have three progress bars in my code(1 main progress bar and 2 sub progress bars). I need to display those progress bars one by one in a new line.

I have tried including the new line inside the function but that is creating a new line for every iteration which will not look good.

```py
        #Progress Bar
    def progress(count, total, status=''):
            bar_len = 40
            filled_len = int(round(bar_len * count / float(total)))

            percents = round(100.0 * count / float(total), 1)
            bar = '=' * filled_len + '-' * (bar_len - filled_len)

            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.write('\r[%s] %s%s - %s\r' % (bar, percents, '%', status))

            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.write("\r")

    def sub_progress_source(count, total, status=''):
            bar_len = 40
            filled_len = int(round(bar_len * count / float(total)))

            percents = round(100.0 * count / float(total), 1)
            bar = '=' * filled_len + '-' * (bar_len - filled_len)

            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.write('\r\n\t[%s] %s%s - %s\r' % (bar, percents, '%', status))

            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.write("\r")

    def sub_progress_target(count, total, status=''):
            bar_len = 40
            filled_len = int(round(bar_len * count / float(total)))

            percents = round(100.0 * count / float(total), 1)
            bar = '=' * filled_len + '-' * (bar_len - filled_len)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.write('\r\n\t[%s] %s%s - %s\r' % (bar, percents, '%', status))    
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.write("\r")
```

```
[====------](Main Progress Bar)
    [====-----](Sub Progress Bar 1)
    [=======--](Sub Progress Bar 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite multiple lines in the console, you need libraries like curses (unix based systems) or win32 console api (windows)

Take a look this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6840469/10389633) answer and following answers on that page to find out more.

Btw you are using way too many '\r' and std.flushes which results in the weird output you are getting :D