# how to update lines on python

Tags: python, terminal

I'm practicing OOP on Python, but i would like to create a "loading screen" on python whichs prints:

```
>>>0%
>>>(_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_)
>>>Adding Oxygen...

#delete the last 3 lines and print*:

>>>1%
>>>(_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_)
>>>Adding Oxygen...

#delete the last 3 lines and print:

>>>2%
>>>(_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_)
>>>Adding Oxygen...

#repeat this until oxygen == 100% print:

>>>100%
>>>(■|■|■|■|■|■|■|■|■|■)
>>>Adding Oxygen...
```

Instead of:

```
0%
Adding oxygen...
1%
Adding oxygen...
2%
Adding oxygen...
3%
Adding oxygen...
4%
Adding oxygen...
5%
Adding oxygen...
6%
Adding oxygen...
7%
Adding oxygen...
8%
Adding oxygen...
9%
Adding oxygen...
(■|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_)
10%
```

I tried to do this using **"\r"** but this deletes only the previous line and it doesn't work with this
Should I use any kind of GUI library to make this posible?

What is the way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewrite multiple lines in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420/rewrite-multiple-lines-in-the-console)

Comment: There is [`tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) for the progress bar. There is [`prompt-toolkit`](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for interactive CLI.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the shell screen from a Python script, you can use (after importing `os`)

```
os.system('cls||clear')
```

You can then rewrite your lines.

Comment: This instruction clears all the previous prints?