# How to delete the last OUTPUT in python console, not the last LINE?

Tags: python, console, output

I'm making a simplistic text adventure game for practice. I want players to be able to backtrack once they go farther into a scenario, for example after they go down a staircase I want them to be able to have "back" as an option and be able to retrace their steps.

I've already figured out every aspect of that except: How to clear the message that popped up telling them about the scenario they just entered.

I have code making their response a variable, and then determining if that variable is one of a set list of viable options, and if not looping them back to the start and deleting their previous entry with the line of code  `print("\033[A                             \033[A")`

However, this code only deletes the last **line** of code, which varies wildly depending on screen ratio and different devices, and not the last output, which is the entire message that described to them the scenario.

Does anyone know a piece of code that can either

- delete the entire last output of the console, in this case a printed line of code which exceeds one line and may extend for as many as 8-10 lines, detailing their scenario, or
- clear the console and then warp them back to my predefined starting point (Example: `def start0():`), because after I clear the console the code `start0()` doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewrite multiple lines in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420/rewrite-multiple-lines-in-the-console)

Comment: Thank you, and maybe? I'm not entirely sure. The top answer seems to be editing a line, which honestly would work fine opposed to sending new prompts each time, but I'm just not sure how I would adjust it to fit with multiple lines of description instead of singular characters on one line. T_T sorry. I'll mess around with it though, thanks.