# How to "Carriage return" with two or more lines simultaneously?

Tags: python, printing, line, carriage-return

```
print("Z1: ",zeta_1_time," Z2: ",zeta_2_time," Z3",zeta_3_time,end="\r")
print()
print("GAMMA: ",gamma_time, end="\r")
```

As you can see from code above, I am having trouble getting carriage \r to function properly. I need both the ZETA times and the GAMMA times to be "updating" on their own line, within the same while loop. However, this is the output I am getting in return.

OUTPUT:

```
Z1:  9  Z2:  6  Z3:  3
Z1:  0  Z2:  0  Z3:  0
GAMMA:  0
```

The longer the while loop, the more lines ZETA creates. Any suggestions?

The output should stay looking like this:

```
Z1:  9  Z2:  6  Z3:  3
GAMMA:  0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewrite multiple lines in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420/rewrite-multiple-lines-in-the-console)

Comment: Not sure I will have to look into this more. If anyone else has any suggestions as well please comment. Thanks

Comment: Just curious if you have tried removing the empty `print()` from your code?