# Creating a progress bar/status in Python text console

Tags: python, python-2.7, progress-bar, console-application

I'm coding a small Python script, that checks the records of a few domains. This is how I do it:

```
if results.short == True:
        isonlist = False
        for dnsbls in L:
                try:
                        if  socket.gethostbyname("%s.%s" % (ip_reversed(results.IP), dnsbls)).startswith("127"):
                                isonlist = True
                except (socket.gaierror):
                        pass
        if isonlist == True:
                print "1"
        else:
                print "0"

else:
        pass
```

Right now it outputs 1 if it get's a valid record and 0 if it doesn't.

Now, I'd like for it to show a progress bar, like when you use wget and the likes.
Tried doing it like this:

```
number = number + 1
```

But that yields me 1 2 3 4 and so forth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002085/python-to-print-out-status-bar-and-percentage

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console/34325723#34325723

Answer (score 4):

My personal favorite for this is [python-progressbar](http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/). It's fast and easy to use.

Comment: I am aware of Python-progressbar, but I was looking for some help implementing the code. While I can find a few things that will work by itself, I can't seem to successfully incorporate it into the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are many progress bar implementation in Python. Some use `curses` or similar terminal libraries (example: http://nadiana.com/animated-terminal-progress-bar-in-python), other use simple `sys.stdout.write('\rstep %d of %d' % (step, max_steps))`

Notice usage of `\r` that means that text you write will replace current line content on console.

Also do not use `number = number + 1`, use `number += 1`

Answer (score 1):

Giorgos Verigakis's has his more recent and rather nice https://github.com/verigak/progress.

Comment: You can "pip install progress" and include it as a dependency, too. See also https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progress