# How can I print multiple lines, having subsequent lines replacing each of them independently (Python)

Tags: python, printing, parallel-processing, percentage, lines

I am running a program that works in parallel, utilizing the `Pool` object from the multiprocessing module.

What I am trying to do is run a function n number of times in parallel, each having a separate loading %, and I would like it to be updating the percentage for each function without replacing other percentages... example:

```
f(x):
    while x < 0:
        print 'For x = {0}, {1}% completed...\r'.format(x, percentage),
```

And I would run the function multiple times in parallel.

The effect I am trying to achieve is the following, for f(10000000), f(15000000), f(7000000):

```
For x = 10000000, 43% completed
For x = 15000000, 31% completed
For x = 7000000, 77% completed
```

And the percentages will be updating in their individual lines without replacing for other values of x, in this function `f` which will be running three times at the same time.

I tried using the carriage return '\r' but that replaces every line and just creates a mess.

Thanks for taking the time to read this post! I hope you can tell me.

I am using Python 2.7 but if it can only be achieved with Python 3 I am open to suggestions.

Comment: have you checked out curses library?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will support multiple concurrent status bars, but you might look at the library referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002085/python-to-print-out-status-bar-and-percentage

Comment: store the output in array, flush output completed, print array again. I'm not sure, just suggestion. I guess, that is what you are searching for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Curses

As @Keozon mentioned in the comments, one way to achieve this would be to use the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) library.

There is a [good guide for curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) on the python website.

## ANSI Escape Codes

Alternatively, you might try using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to move the cursor around.

This is in Python3, but it'll work just fine in any version, you'll just need to change the print statements around (or `from __future__ import print_function`).

```
print('Hello')                                     
print('World')                                     
                                                   
print('\033[F\033[F\033[K', end='') # Up, Up, Clear line
                                                   
# Cursor is at the 'H' of 'Hello'                  
                                                   
print('Hi') # Overwriting 'Hello'                  
                                                   
# Cursor is at the 'W' of 'World'                  
                                                   
print('\033[E', end='') # Down                     
                                                   
# Cursor is on the blank line after 'World'        
                                                   
print('Back to the end')
```

### Output:

```
Hi         
World          
Back to the end
```

---

## Edit:

I've done way too much work for you here, but hey, here's basically a full solution using the ANSI method I mentioned above:

```
import time
import random


class ProgressBar:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self._progress = 0

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def get_progress(self):
        """
        Randomly increment the progress bar and ensure it doesn't go
        over 100
        """
        self._progress += int(random.random()*5)
        if self._progress > 100:
            self._progress = 100

        return self._progress


class MultipleProgressBars:
    def __init__(self, progress_bars):
        self._progress_bars = progress_bars
        self._first_update = True
        self._all_finished = False

    @property
    def all_finished(self):
        """
        A boolean indicating if all progress bars are at 100
        """
        return self._all_finished

    def update(self):
        """
        Update each progress bar
        """
        # We don't want to move up and clear a line on the first run
        # so we have a flag to make sure this only happens on later
        # calls
        if not self._first_update:
            # Move up and clear the line the correct number of times
            print('\033[F\033[K'*len(self._progress_bars),end='', sep='')

        num_complete = 0  # Number of progress bars complete
        for progress_bar in self._progress_bars:
            name = progress_bar.name
            progress = progress_bar.get_progress()

            if progress == 100:
                num_complete += 1

            # Print out a progress bar (scaled to 40 chars wide)
            print(
                name.ljust(10),
                '[' + ('='*int(progress*0.4)).ljust(40) + ']',
                str(progress)+'%')

        if num_complete == len(self._progress_bars):
            self._all_finished = True

        self._first_update = False  # Mark the first update done


# Create a list of ProgressBars and give them relevant names
progress_bars = [
    ProgressBar('James'),
    ProgressBar('Bert'),
    ProgressBar('Alfred'),
    ProgressBar('Frank')
]

# Create a new instance of our MultipleProgressBars class
mpb = MultipleProgressBars(progress_bars)

# Keep updating them while at least one of them is still active
while not mpb.all_finished:
    mpb.update()
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will go try that later and come back with the results!

Comment: Note that this merely writes on top, so writing `hello` on top of `pancake` would result in `helloke`.  I believe it is `\033[K` that clears everything from the cursor to the end of the line.

Comment: @zondo Yea, you're right. I've updated my answer to rectify this.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I really appreciate it. The issue I have is that since the function is running in parallel, there is no way to there where each % for each different x will be, so I cannot know which line I want to replace in each print. For example: The function is printing `some % loaded for x = some number`, and is randomly printing since it's all running at the same time. The only thing I could come up with is selecting a printing line for `x = some number` but that would be if I knew each value of `x`, making it inefficient.

Comment: You'll probably have to change the way it's working to get it to work as you want it to unfortunately. Just in case you're not aware, python has a [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) this means that depending on what you're using threading for, you mightn't actually get a performance benefit. However, "potentially blocking or long-running operations, such as I/O, image processing, and NumPy number crunching, happen outside the GIL", so it depends on what you're doing in your threads.