# Progress bar for a "for" loop in Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use a progress bar in a python script that I have since I have a for loop that takes quite a bit of time to process. I have looked at other explanations on here already but I am still confused. Here is what my for loop looks like in my script:

```
for member in members:
    url = "http://api.wiki123.com/v1.11/member?id="+str(member) 
    header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}
    api_response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    member_check = json.loads(api_response.text)
    member_status = member_check.get("response")
```

I have read a bit about using the `progressbar` library but my confusion lies in where I have to put the code to support a progress bar relative to my for loop I have included here.

Comment: I've published a new kind of progress bar, which you can print, see throughput and eta, even pause it, besides the very cool animations!

Please take a look: https://github.com/rsalmei/alive-progress
![alive-progress](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rsalmei/alive-progress/master/img/main.gif)

Comment: This post is awesome because I think all the following answers are useful and it just depends on your need.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Using [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/):

```
from tqdm import tqdm

for member in tqdm(members):
    # current contents of your for loop
```

`tqdm()` takes `members` and iterates over it, but each time it yields a new member (between each iteration of the loop), it also updates a progress bar on your command line. That makes this actually quite similar to Matthias' solution (printing stuff at the end of each loop iteration), but the progressbar update logic is nicely encapsulated inside `tqdm`.

Comment: That was hard to search because my stupid brain assumed that `for i in tqdm(range(10))` weren't allowing for `for in` iteration.

Answer (score 48):

To show the progress bar:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

for x in tqdm(my_list):
    # do something with x

#### In case using with enumerate:
for i, x in enumerate( tqdm(my_list) ):
    # do something with i and x
```

[image]

*Some notes on the attached picture*:

`49%`: It already finished 49% of the whole process

`979/2000`: Working on the 979th element/iteration, out of 2000 elements/iterations

`01:50`: It's been running for 1 minute and 50 seconds

`01:55`: Estimated time left to run

`8.81 it/s`: On average, it processes 8.81 elements per second

Answer (score 8):

I think this could be most elegantly be solved in this manner:

```
import progressbar

bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=len(members)).start()

for idx, member in enumerate(members):
    ...
    bar.update(idx)
```

Comment: As many would suspect, the first line results in an error: `NameError: name 'progressbar' is not defined`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you need to install the package and include it.

Comment: @nammerkage It was a subtle hint for author to add `import` into code. I wrote my own progress bar not requiring imports BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70586588/6929343

Answer (score 5):

The basic idea of a progress bar from a loop is to insert points within the loop to update the progress bar. An example would be something like this:

```
membersProcessed = 0
for member in members:
    url = "http://api.wiki123.com/v1.11/member?id="+str(member) 
    header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}
    api_response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    member_check = json.loads(api_response.text)
    member_status = member_check.get("response") 

    membersProcessed += 1
    print 'Progress: {}/{} members processed'.format(membersProcessed, len(members))
```

Maybe this helps.

And you could include a more detailed one by adding points after certain commands within the for loop as well.

Comment: When running the code on jupyter notebook, the browser will break if it has a lot of outputs

Answer (score 4):

The [rich module](https://pypi.org/project/rich/) has also a progress bar that can be included in your for loop:

```
import time  # for demonstration only
from rich.progress import track

members = ['Liam', 'Olivia', 'Noah', 'Emma', 'Oliver', 'Charlotte']  # for demonstration only

for member in track(members):
    # your code here
    print(member)  # for demonstration only
    time.sleep(1.5)  # for demonstration only
```

Note: `time` is only used to get the delay for the screenshot.

Here's a screenshot from within the run:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this (can be used for any situation):

```
for i in tqdm (range (1), desc="Loading..."):
    for member in members:
       url = "http://api.wiki123.com/v1.11/member?id="+str(member) 
       header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}
       api_response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
       member_check = json.loads(api_response.text)
       member_status = member_check.get("response")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here Is a simple progress bar code with 0 imports

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
def progressbar(current_value,total_value,bar_lengh,progress_char): 
    percentage = int((current_value/total_value)*100)                                                # Percent Completed Calculation 
    progress = int((bar_lengh * current_value ) / total_value)                                       # Progress Done Calculation 
    loadbar = "Progress: [{:{len}}]{}%".format(progress*progress_char,percentage,len = bar_lengh)    # Progress Bar String
    print(loadbar, end='\r')                                                                         # Progress Bar Output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    the_list = range(1,301) 
    for i in the_list:
        progressbar(i,len(the_list),30,'■')
    print("\n")
```

[image]
You can implement it like so in your case.

```
def progressbar(current_value,total_value,bar_lengh,progress_char): 
    percentage = int((current_value/total_value)*100)                                            
    progress = int((bar_lengh * current_value ) / total_value)                                   
    loadbar = "Progress: [{:{len}}]{}%".format(progress*progress_char,percentage,len = bar_lengh)
    print(loadbar, end='\r')                                                                     

for member in members:
    url = "http://api.wiki123.com/v1.11/member?id="+str(member) 
    header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}
    api_response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    member_check = json.loads(api_response.text)
    member_status = member_check.get("response")
    progressbar(member,len(members),30,'■')         # (Current iteration, Total iterations, Progress bar lenght, Progress bar character)
print("\n")                                         # New Line After Progress Bar Completed
```