# How do I add a progress bar in this function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text preprocessing function like this:

```
def preprocessing(text):
    
    text = text.lower()
    text = "".join([char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation])
    words = word_tokenize(text)
    words = [word for word in words if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
    words = [PorterStemmer().stem(word) for word in words]
    
    return words
```

And I am going to pass a dataframe in this function like this:

```
df['reviewText'] = df['reviewText'].apply(lambda x: preprocessing(x))
```

But the dataframe column has around 10000 reviews sentences, and the code taking too much time to complete. Is there any way to add a 'progress bar' so that I will have some understanding of time.

PS. If you want to try this on your local machine, the data can be found on [this site](https://www.kaggle.com/meetnagadia/amazon-kindle-book-sentiment-analysis/data).

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259717/progress-bar-for-a-for-loop-in-python-script ?

Comment: @Greg I don't think so, my function do not have any for loop and I don't know how to implement that answer. I know it is too much to ask in SO, but can you tell me (in answer section) how to apply that `tqdm` in my preprocessing function?

Comment: You have 3 `for` loops, they've been shorten to 1 liners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import TQDM and replace `.apply()` with `.progress_apply()`:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

df['reviewText'] = df['reviewText'].progress_apply(lambda x: preprocessing(x))
```

Comment: hah, didn't know there was a builtin... [on the dataframe]

Comment: I don't think there is, it's mostly likely `tqdm.pandas()` [monkeypatching](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) it in.

Comment: Yes, not sure what I was thinking there

Answer (score 1):

If you want a progress bar you *have* to have a loop: a progress bar is by definition a loop.  Fortunately you have one here in the `apply`.  As a very quick trivial solution without ceasing to use apply, I would have the function update the progress bar as a side effect:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
t = tqdm(total=len(df.index))

def fn(x, state=[0]):
    preprocessing(x)
    state[0] += 1
    t.update(state[0])
df['reviewText'] = df['reviewText'].apply(fn)

t.close()
```

Whether this is clearer than writing the loop out explicitly is your call; I'm not sure it is.

(What's with the `state=[0]`?  We're defining a muteable kwarg, which gets allocated once, for the fn, and then using it to keep track of state, as we have to manage state manually with this approach.)

### Explicit loop

```py
applied = []
for row in tqdm(df["reviewText"]):
    applied.append(preprocessing(row)

df["reviewText"] = applied
```