# How to show status in a very slow loop in python

Tags: python, performance, loops, output, status

I want to show status every second in a very slow loop in python code, e.g.

```
for i in range(100):
    sleep(1000000) # think there is a very slow job

    # I want to show status in console every second
    # to know if the job stop or not
```

The output image is, e.g.

```
$ python somejob.py
> 2022-09-02 13:04:10 | Status: running...
```

and the output updates every second, e.g.

```
$ python somejob.py
> 2022-09-02 13:04:11 | Status: running...
```

```
$ python somejob.py
> 2022-09-02 13:04:12 | Status: running...
```

```
$ python somejob.py
> 2022-09-02 13:04:13 | Status: running...
```

Any idea will by helpful. Thx!!!

Comment: progress bar is even better idea. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259717/progress-bar-for-a-for-loop-in-python-script

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is someting like the tqdm library: [github repo](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm)

for example

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(1000)):
    continue # do something complex here
```

Answer (score 0):

You may us the [rich module](https://pypi.org/project/rich/) to disply a progress bar:

```
import time
from rich.progress import track

for i in track(range(100)):
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Here's a screenshot within the run:
[image]