# Creating string of repeated characters in shell script

Tags: unix, shell

I need to generate a string of dots (`.`characters) as a variable.

I.e., in my Bash script, for input `15` I need to generate this string of length 15: `...............`

I need to do so variably. I tried using this as a base ([from Unix.com](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/46584-repeat-character-printf.html)):

```
for i in {1..100};do printf "%s" "#";done;printf "\n"
```

But how do I get the 100 to be a variable?

Comment: Related on [SU]: http://superuser.com/q/86340/269404

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5349718/2157640 http://stackoverflow.com/q/5799303/2157640

Comment: In `zsh` at least, `{1..$length}` works just fine.

Comment: n=15; chr='.'; txt=''; for((i=0; $i<$n; i++)); do txt=$txt$chr; done; echo "$txt"

Comment: This is so badly needed when I use zsh `bindkey` with `^[[D` to move the cursor back into a useful place!

Answer (score 90):

You can get as many NULL bytes as you want from /dev/zero. You can then turn these into other characters. The following prints 16 lowercase a's

```
head -c 16 < /dev/zero | tr '\0' '\141'
```

Comment: +1 for a sweet and portable solution without filthy bashisms or hundreds of processes being spawned

Comment: you can use /dev/zero directly, no need to redirect

Comment: Not *that* sweet and portable: "head: illegal option -- c" (SunOS 5.10 Generic_150401-20 i86pc i386 i86pc)

Comment: `head -c` is portable only on GNU and BSD utils, it's not POSIX.

Comment: You can use `dd` instead with `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=16` replacind the `head` part.

Comment: `head -n` is [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html)

Answer (score 45):

```
len=100 ch='#'
printf '%*s' "$len" | tr ' ' "$ch"
```

Comment: This is the shortest [POSIX 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94) solution I have seen so far.

Comment: can be even shorter, take out the quotation in "$len" to be $len ;)

Comment: `shellcheck` says you are risking code injection without the quotes on `"$len"`.

Comment: @JesseChisholm using `shellcheck` you are risking corporate code into someone else's hands ;)

Answer (score 28):

**Easiest and shortest way without a loop**

```
VAR=15
```

Prints as many dots as VAR says (change the first dot to any other character if you like):

```
printf '.%.0s' {1..$VAR}
```

Saves the dotted line in a variable to be used later:

```
line=`printf '.%.0s' {1..$VAR}`
echo "Sign here $line"
```

-Blatantly stolen from dogbane's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/3319298

**Edit**: Since I have now switched to  **fish** shell, here is a function defined in config.fish that does this with convenience in that shell:

```
function line -a char -a length
  printf '%*s\n' $length "" | tr ' ' $char
end
```

Usage: `line = 8` produces `========`, `line \" 8` produces `""""""""`.

Comment: what an interesting way to exploit printf's shell feature that repeatibly consumes arguments until satisfied in combination with a zero-field width, forcing just the string before the % to be printed. This could be used as a trick to divide the count as well (adding the %.0s twice to force it to consume 2 arguments per pass)

Comment: oh yeah and I forgot something important, since printf processes %s with a null if no args are given, a value of zero would be a problem, for that you would have to add an if statement

Comment: This only works for me in my shell (bash) if I use eval: `VAR=15 ; eval printf '=%.0s' {1..$VAR}`

Comment: Only works for me with eval too. Replacing $VAR with $COLUMNS is very useful for making a horizontal ruler. If needed from inside a script: `hr () { eval printf '=%.0s' {1..$(tput cols)}; echo; }`

Comment: Your answer is fine, using *POSIX shell*, but using [tag:bash] , you could avoid one fork by using `-v` arg to `printf -v  line '.%.0s' {1..$VAR}`

Comment: @6EQUJ5 In `bash`, you can't use variables in a brace expansion. Instead, you can use `$(seq 1 $VAR)` in place of `{1..$VAR}`

Comment: @wisbucky actually it does... tested exactly what I quoted above just now using bash version 4.3.30(1)-release on Debian 8 - maybe you have a different shell

```~$ VAR=15 ; eval printf '=%.0s' {1..$VAR}``` (line break was here)
```===============```

Comment: @6EQUJ5 I meant without using `eval`. `eval` is not safe to use in a script. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead

Answer (score 9):

On most systems, you could get away with a simple

```
N=100
myvar=`perl -e "print '.' x $N;"`
```

Answer (score 6):

I demonstrated a way to accomplish this task with a single command in another question, assuming it's a fixed number of characters to be produced.

I added an addendum to the end about producing a variable number of repeated characters, which is what you asked for, so my previous answer is relevant here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030976/2284005

I provided a full explanation of how it works there. Here I'll just add the code to accomplish what you're asking for:

```
    n=20 # This the number of characters you want to produce

    variable=$(printf "%0.s." $(seq 1 $n)) # Fill $variable with $n periods

    echo $variable # Output content of $variable to terminal
```

Outputs:

```
....................
```

Comment: n=0 fails to produce the correct number of characters.  As do most of the printf solutions.

Answer (score 4):

The solution without loops:

```
N=100
myvar=`seq 1 $N | sed 's/.*/./' | tr -d '\n'`
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use C-style `for` loops in Bash:

```
num=100
string=$(for ((i=1; i<=$num; i++));do printf "%s" "#";done;printf "\n")
```

Or without a loop, using `printf` without using any externals such as `sed` or `tr`:

```
num=100
printf -v string "%*s" $num ' ' '' $'\n'
string=${string// /#}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
num=100
myvar=$(jot -b . -s '' $num)
echo $myvar
```

Answer (score -1):

When I have to create a string that contains `$x` repetitions of a known character with `$x` below a constant value, I use this idiom:

```
base='....................'
# 0 <= $x <= ${#base}
x=5
expr "x$base" : "x\(.\{$x\}\)"    # Will output '\n' too
```

Output:

```
.....
```

Comment: In bash and ksh (perhaps zsh), you could write `echo ${base:0:$x}` -- details [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)