# How can I repeat a character in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, echo

How could I do this with `echo`?

```sh
perl -E 'say "=" x 100'
```

Comment: Sadly this is not Bash.

Comment: not with echo, but on the same topic `ruby -e 'puts "=" * 100'` or `python -c 'print "=" * 100'`

Comment: Great question. Very good answers. I've used one of the answers in a real job here, that I'll post as an example: https://github.com/drbeco/oldfiles/blob/master/oldfiles (used `printf` with `seq`) `svrb=\`printf '%.sv' $(seq $vrb)\``

Comment: A generic solution to print whatever (1 or more characters, even including newlines): Repeat_this () { i=1; while [ "$i" -le "$2" ]; do printf "%s" "$1"; i=$(( $i + 1 )) ; done ; printf '\n' ;} . Use like this: Repeat_this "something" Number_of_repetitions. For example, to showcase repeating 5 times something including 3 newlines: Repeat_this "$(printf '\n\n\nthis')" 5 . The final printf '\n' may be taken out (but I put it in to create text files, and those need a newline as their last character!)

Comment: Using `Perl` is already good enough for me. Tried several answers but they all have a `%` at the end of the string, don't know why.

Comment: Ok, just found out why, it should be `Perl -E 'print "=" x 100'`

Answer (score 548, accepted):

You can use:

```
printf '=%.0s' {1..100}
```

How this works:

Bash expands `{1..100}` so the command becomes:

```
printf '=%.0s' 1 2 3 4 ... 100
```

I've set printf's format to `=%.0s` which means that it will always print a single `=` no matter what argument it is given. Therefore it prints 100 `=`s.

Comment: Great solution that performs reasonably well even with large repeat counts. Here's a function wrapper you can invoke with `repl = 100`, for instance (`eval` trickery is required, unfortunately, for basing the brace expansion on a variable): `repl() { printf "$1"'%.s' $(eval "echo {1.."$(($2))"}"); }`

Comment: Is it possible to set the upper limit using a var? I've tried and can't get it to work.

Comment: You can't use variables within brace expansion. Use `seq` instead e.g. `$(seq 1 $limit)`.

Comment: Here's another function that uses a word as the argument and prints based on the number of chars in the word: `repl () { printf '=%.0s' $(seq 2 $(echo $1 | wc -c)); }` Usage: `repl 'Installing something'` or `repl "Installing $package"`

Comment: You can use variables with brace expansion in `ksh` and `zsh`, unfortunately it's just `bash` which expands things in a different and silly order.

Comment: If you functionalise this it's best to rearrange it from `$s%.0s` to `%.0s$s` otherwise dashes cause a `printf` error.

Comment: @dogbane `n=5; eval "echo {1..$n}"` But seq is more elegant.

Comment: This made me notice a behaviour of Bash's `printf`: it continues to apply the format string until there are no arguments left. I had assumed it processed the format string only once!

Comment: If you want to specify the width using a variable `w`, how about `printf "%${w}s" '' | tr ' ' =`?

Comment: You also can use:

`len=20;
eval "printf "%0.s$c" {1..$len}"`

Comment: it also works without zero following the dot: `echo "$(printf '=%.s' {1..100})"`

Comment: +1 on answer but I still went with `Equals="============="` and `Dashes="------------"` defined in bash global section and then referenced in printing loops within local bash functions for performance and readability. Feeling kind of guilty today but I know I'll appreciate the KISS system 5 years from now.

Comment: If trying to repeat hyphens `-`, you can put them at the end of the format string `'%.0s-'`, otherwise you will get an error because the leading hyphen will be interpreted as an option.

Comment: To add a newline you can do: echo $(printf '=%.0s' {1..100})

Comment: `printf '=%.0s'` outputs `=`. So, not an option when you need arbitrary number of `=`'s. Or to be precise, arbitrary number of spaces to make an indent. The [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349796/52499) solution accommodates this case just fine. Namely, `printf "%${n}s" | tr ' ' '='`

Comment: what is meaning behind `.0` mean in this answer? And is this regex or `printf`

Comment: @0x476f72616e From `man 3 printf`: "An  optional  precision,  in the form of a period ('.')  followed by an optional decimal digit string. [..] If the precision is given as just '.', the precision is taken to be zero. [..] the maximum number of  characters to be printed from a string for s and S conversions." Therefore, I'd expect it to work without the `0` too.

Comment: If you do this in vim, you'll need to escape the `%`. Try adding a comment line in LaTeX: `read !printf '\%\%\%.s' {1..50}`

Comment: Simply as ```echo {1..100}```

Comment: Z shell: use `PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''` to [hide trailing percent symbol at EOL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167600).

Answer (score 130):

No easy way. But for example:

```
seq -s= 100|tr -d '[:digit:]'
# Editor's note: This requires BSD seq, and breaks with GNU seq (see comments)
```

Or maybe a standard-conforming way:

```
printf %100s |tr " " "="
```

There's also a `tput rep`, but as for my terminals at hand (xterm and linux) they don't seem to support it:)

Comment: Note that the first option with seq prints one less than the number given, so that example will print 99 `=` characters.

Comment: `printf` `tr` is the only POSIX solution because `seq`, `yes` and `{1..3}` are not POSIX.

Comment: To repeat a string rather than just a single character: `printf %100s | sed 's/ /abc/g'` - outputs 'abcabcabc...'

Comment: +1 for using no loops and only one external command (`tr`). You could also extend it to something like `printf "%${COLUMNS}s\n" | tr " " "="`.

Comment: @CamiloMartin: I don't see that; both GNU and BSD `seq` seem to be returning the expected 100 chars. when I run `seq -s= 100 | tr -d '[:digit:]' | wc -m`. If it really doesn't work for you: what `seq` implementation are you using?

Comment: @mklement0 On Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, that comes with GNU `seq` 8.21, I get one less than the number given; [see screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/lp8kvwp.png). Now I ask on which platform you are, because I thought this was consistent. Here's [a screenshot on a RaspberryPi](http://i.imgur.com/eqH99FV.png) and [even on Windows](http://i.imgur.com/7l88JWu.png).

Comment: @CamiloMartin: Thanks for the follow-up: It indeed comes down to the `seq` implementation (and thus implicitly the platform): _GNU_ `seq` (Linux) produces _1 fewer_ `=` than the number specified (unlike what I originally claimed, but as you've correctly determined), whereas _BSD_ `seq` (BSD-like platforms, including OSX) produces the desired number.
Simple test command: `seq -s= 100 | tr -d '[:digit:]\n' | wc -c`
BSD `seq` places `=` after _every_ number, _including the last_, whereas GNU seq places a _newline_ after the _last_ number, thus coming up short by 1 with respect to the `=` count.

Comment: @mklement0 Well, I was hoping you were counting the last newline by mistake with `wc`. The only conclusion I can take from this is "`seq` shouldn't be used".

Comment: @CamiloMartin: Agreed: the `printf` solution is the portable one - and simpler to boot.

Comment: I could not get `tput rep` to work, but the direct ANSI sequence works. I think that `tput` fails to properly handle the `termcap` syntax of `rep=%p1%c\E[%p2%{1}%-%db` or Gnome Terminal's Termcap is missing the entry. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59251780/7939871

Comment: The standard-conforming use of `printf` worked fine under the POSIX shell for me. Many thanks.

Comment: Using printf %*s syntax: `printf "%*s" ${nb} | tr ' ' "${car}"`

Answer (score 84):

<sup>Tip of the hat to @[gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) for his input.</sup>

Note: This answer does *not* answer the original question, but ***complements* the existing, helpful answers by *comparing performance*.**

Solutions are **compared in terms of execution speed only** - memory requirements are *not* taken into account (they vary across solutions and may matter with large repeat counts).

**Summary:**

- If your **repeat count is *small***, say up to around 100, it's **worth going with the *Bash-only solutions***, as the startup cost of external utilities matters, especially Perl's.

  - Pragmatically speaking, however, if you only  need *one* instance of repeating characters, all existing solutions may be fine.
- With ***large* repeat counts**, **use *external utilities***, as they'll be much faster.

  - In particular, avoid Bash's global substring replacement with large strings
    (e.g., `${var// /=}`), as it is prohibitively slow.

The following are **timings** taken on a late-2012 iMac with a 3.2 GHz Intel Core i5 CPU and a Fusion Drive, running OSX 10.10.4 and bash 3.2.57, and are the average of 1000 runs.

The entries are:

- listed in ascending order of execution duration (fastest first)
- prefixed with:

  - `M` ... a potentially *multi*-character solution
  - `S` ... a *single*-character-only solution
  - `P` ... a POSIX-compliant solution
- followed by a brief description of the solution
- suffixed with the name of the author of the originating answer

---

- Small repeat count: 100

```
[M, P] printf %.s= [dogbane]:                           0.0002
[M   ] printf + bash global substr. replacement [Tim]:  0.0005
[M   ] echo -n - brace expansion loop [eugene y]:       0.0007
[M   ] echo -n - arithmetic loop [Eliah Kagan]:         0.0013
[M   ] seq -f [Sam Salisbury]:                          0.0016
[M   ] jot -b [Stefan Ludwig]:                          0.0016
[M   ] awk - $(count+1)="=" [Steven Penny (variant)]:   0.0019
[M, P] awk - while loop [Steven Penny]:                 0.0019
[S   ] printf + tr [user332325]:                        0.0021
[S   ] head + tr [eugene y]:                            0.0021
[S, P] dd + tr [mklement0]:                             0.0021
[M   ] printf + sed [user332325 (comment)]:             0.0021
[M   ] mawk - $(count+1)="=" [Steven Penny (variant)]:  0.0025
[M, P] mawk - while loop [Steven Penny]:                0.0026
[M   ] gawk - $(count+1)="=" [Steven Penny (variant)]:  0.0028
[M, P] gawk - while loop [Steven Penny]:                0.0028
[M   ] yes + head + tr [Digital Trauma]:                0.0029
[M   ] Perl [sid_com]:                                  0.0059
```

- The Bash-only solutions lead the pack - but only with a repeat count this small! (see below).
- Startup cost of external utilities does matter here, especially Perl's. If you must call this in a loop - with *small* repetition counts in each iteration - avoid the multi-utility, `awk`, and `perl` solutions.

---

- Large repeat count: 1000000 (1 million)

```
[M   ] Perl [sid_com]:                                  0.0067
[M   ] mawk - $(count+1)="=" [Steven Penny (variant)]:  0.0254
[M   ] gawk - $(count+1)="=" [Steven Penny (variant)]:  0.0599
[S   ] head + tr [eugene y]:                            0.1143
[S, P] dd + tr [mklement0]:                             0.1144
[S   ] printf + tr [user332325]:                        0.1164
[M, P] mawk - while loop [Steven Penny]:                0.1434
[M   ] seq -f [Sam Salisbury]:                          0.1452
[M   ] jot -b [Stefan Ludwig]:                          0.1690
[M   ] printf + sed [user332325 (comment)]:             0.1735
[M   ] yes + head + tr [Digital Trauma]:                0.1883
[M, P] gawk - while loop [Steven Penny]:                0.2493
[M   ] awk - $(count+1)="=" [Steven Penny (variant)]:   0.2614
[M, P] awk - while loop [Steven Penny]:                 0.3211
[M, P] printf %.s= [dogbane]:                           2.4565
[M   ] echo -n - brace expansion loop [eugene y]:       7.5877
[M   ] echo -n - arithmetic loop [Eliah Kagan]:         13.5426
[M   ] printf + bash global substr. replacement [Tim]:  n/a
```

- The Perl solution from the question is by far the fastest.
- Bash's global string-replacement (`${foo// /=}`) is inexplicably excruciatingly slow with large strings, and has been taken out of the running (took around 50 minutes(!) in Bash 4.3.30, and even longer in Bash 3.2.57 - I never waited for it to finish).
- Bash loops are slow, and arithmetic loops (`(( i= 0; ... ))`) are slower than brace-expanded ones (`{1..n}`) - though arithmetic loops are more memory-efficient.
- `awk` refers to *BSD* `awk` (as also found on OSX) - it's noticeably slower than `gawk` (GNU Awk) and especially `mawk`.
- Note that with large counts and multi-char. strings, memory consumption can become a consideration - the approaches differ in that respect.

---

Here's the **Bash script** (`testrepeat`) that produced the above.
It takes 2 arguments:

- the character repeat count
- optionally, the number of test runs to perform and to calculate the *average* timing from

In other words: the timings above were obtained with `testrepeat 100 1000` and `testrepeat 1000000 1000`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

title() { printf '%s:\t' "$1"; }

TIMEFORMAT=$'%6Rs'

# The number of repetitions of the input chars. to produce
COUNT_REPETITIONS=${1?Arguments: <charRepeatCount> [<testRunCount>]}

# The number of test runs to perform to derive the average timing from.
COUNT_RUNS=${2:-1}

# Discard the (stdout) output generated by default.
# If you want to check the results, replace '/dev/null' on the following
# line with a prefix path to which a running index starting with 1 will
# be appended for each test run; e.g., outFilePrefix='outfile', which
# will produce outfile1, outfile2, ...
outFilePrefix=/dev/null

{

  outFile=$outFilePrefix
  ndx=0

  title '[M, P] printf %.s= [dogbane]'
  [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
  # !! In order to use brace expansion with a variable, we must use `eval`.
  eval "
  time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
    printf '%.s=' {1..$COUNT_REPETITIONS} >"$outFile"
  done"

  title '[M   ] echo -n - arithmetic loop [Eliah Kagan]'
  [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
  time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
    for ((i=0; i<COUNT_REPETITIONS; ++i)); do echo -n =; done >"$outFile"
  done


  title '[M   ] echo -n - brace expansion loop [eugene y]'
  [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
  # !! In order to use brace expansion with a variable, we must use `eval`.
  eval "
  time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
    for i in {1..$COUNT_REPETITIONS}; do echo -n =; done >"$outFile"
  done
  "

  title '[M   ] printf + sed [user332325 (comment)]'
  [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
  time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
    printf "%${COUNT_REPETITIONS}s" | sed 's/ /=/g' >"$outFile"
  done


  title '[S   ] printf + tr [user332325]'
  [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
  time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
    printf "%${COUNT_REPETITIONS}s" | tr ' ' '='  >"$outFile"
  done


  title '[S   ] head + tr [eugene y]'
  [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
  time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
    head -c $COUNT_REPETITIONS < /dev/zero | tr '\0' '=' >"$outFile"
  done


  title '[M   ] seq -f [Sam Salisbury]'
  [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
  time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
    seq -f '=' -s '' $COUNT_REPETITIONS >"$outFile"
  done


  title '[M   ] jot -b [Stefan Ludwig]'
  [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
  time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
    jot -s '' -b '=' $COUNT_REPETITIONS >"$outFile"
  done


  title '[M   ] yes + head + tr [Digital Trauma]'
  [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
  time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
    yes = | head -$COUNT_REPETITIONS | tr -d '\n'  >"$outFile"
  done

  title '[M   ] Perl [sid_com]'
  [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
  time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
    perl -e "print \"=\" x $COUNT_REPETITIONS" >"$outFile"
  done

  title '[S, P] dd + tr [mklement0]'
  [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
  time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
    dd if=/dev/zero bs=$COUNT_REPETITIONS count=1 2>/dev/null | tr '\0' "=" >"$outFile"
  done

  # !! On OSX, awk is BSD awk, and mawk and gawk were installed later.
  # !! On Linux systems, awk may refer to either mawk or gawk.
  for awkBin in awk mawk gawk; do
    if [[ -x $(command -v $awkBin) ]]; then

      title "[M   ] $awkBin"' - $(count+1)="=" [Steven Penny (variant)]'
      [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
      time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
        $awkBin -v count=$COUNT_REPETITIONS 'BEGIN { OFS="="; $(count+1)=""; print }' >"$outFile"
      done

      title "[M, P] $awkBin"' - while loop [Steven Penny]'
      [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
      time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
        $awkBin -v count=$COUNT_REPETITIONS 'BEGIN { while (i++ < count) printf "=" }' >"$outFile"
      done

    fi
  done

  title '[M   ] printf + bash global substr. replacement [Tim]'
  [[ $outFile != '/dev/null' ]] && outFile="$outFilePrefix$((++ndx))"
  # !! In Bash 4.3.30 a single run with repeat count of 1 million took almost
  # !! 50 *minutes*(!) to complete; n Bash 3.2.57 it's seemingly even slower -
  # !! didn't wait for it to finish.
  # !! Thus, this test is skipped for counts that are likely to be much slower
  # !! than the other tests.
  skip=0
  [[ $BASH_VERSINFO -le 3 && COUNT_REPETITIONS -gt 1000 ]] && skip=1
  [[ $BASH_VERSINFO -eq 4 && COUNT_REPETITIONS -gt 10000 ]] && skip=1
  if (( skip )); then
    echo 'n/a' >&2
  else
    time for (( n = 0; n < COUNT_RUNS; n++ )); do 
      { printf -v t "%${COUNT_REPETITIONS}s" '='; printf %s "${t// /=}"; } >"$outFile"
    done
  fi
} 2>&1 | 
 sort -t$'\t' -k2,2n | 
   awk -F $'\t' -v count=$COUNT_RUNS '{ 
    printf "%s\t", $1; 
    if ($2 ~ "^n/a") { print $2 } else { printf "%.4f\n", $2 / count }}' |
     column -s$'\t' -t
```

Comment: It's interesting to see timing comparison, but I think in many programs output is buffered, so their timing can be altered if buffering was turned off.

Comment: `In order to use brace expansion with a variable, we must use \`eval\`` 

Comment: So the perl solution (sid_com) is basically the fastest ... once the initial overhead of launching perl is reached. (it goes from 59ms for a small repeat to 67ms for a million repeats... so the perl forking took approximately 59ms on your system)

Comment: Funny, that using the char `*` result of my list of files in the current directory being grabbed to the variable when doing: `myvar=$(printf -- '*%.0s' {1..5})`

Comment: @RickyLevi, that only happens if you use `$myvar` _unquoted_ in a later command, in which case _pathname expansion_ (globbing) predictably happens. Use `echo "$myvar"` to see that `$myvar` itself was correctly filled with verbatim ``*****.

Answer (score 62):

There's more than one way to do it.

**Using a loop:**

- Brace expansion can be used with integer literals:

  ```
  for i in {1..100}; do echo -n =; done
  ```
- A C-like loop allows the use of variables:

  ```
  start=1
  end=100
  for ((i=$start; i<=$end; i++)); do echo -n =; done
  ```

**Using the `printf` builtin:**

```
printf '=%.0s' {1..100}
```

Specifying a precision here truncates the string to fit the specified width (`0`). As `printf` reuses the format string to consume all of the arguments, this simply prints `"="` 100 times.

**Using `head` (`printf`, etc) and `tr`:**

```
head -c 100 < /dev/zero | tr '\0' '='
printf %100s | tr " " "="
```

Comment: ++ for the `head` / `tr` solution, which works well even with high repeat counts (small caveat: `head -c` is not POSIX-compliant, but both BSD and GNU `head` implement it); while the other two solutions will be slow in that case, they do have the advantage of working with _multi_-character strings, too.

Comment: Using `yes` and `head` -- useful if you want a certain number of newlines: `yes "" | head -n 100`. `tr` can make it print any character: `yes "" | head -n 100 | tr "\n" "="; echo`

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly: `dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=100000000 | tr '\0' '=' >/dev/null` is significantly slower than the `head -c100000000 < /dev/zero | tr '\0' '=' >/dev/null` version. Of course you have to use a block size of 100M+ to measure the time difference reasonably. 100M bytes takes 1.7 s and 1 s with the two respective versions shown. I took off the tr and just dumped it to `/dev/null` and got 0.287 s for the `head` version and 0.675 s for the `dd` version for a billion bytes.

Comment: For: `dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=100000000 | tr '\0' '=' >/dev/null` => `0,21332 s, 469 MB/s`;

For: `dd if=/dev/zero count=100 bs=1000000| tr '\0' '=' >/dev/null` => `0,161579 s, 619 MB/s`;

Comment: Used `printf`/`tr` to print caption and '=' line underneath:
`CAPTION="Test Suite Results" && echo "${CAPTION}" && printf "%${#CAPTION}s\n" | tr " " "=" && echo`
Works on Mac & Linux just fine.

Answer (score 38):

I've just found a seriously easy way to do this using seq:

**UPDATE: This works on the BSD `seq` that comes with OS X. YMMV with other versions**

```
seq  -f "#" -s '' 10
```

Will print '#' 10 times, like this:

```
##########
```

- `-f "#"` sets the format string to ignore the numbers and just print `#` for each one.
- `-s ''` sets the separator to an empty string to remove the newlines that seq inserts between each number
- The spaces after `-f` and `-s` seem to be important.

**EDIT: Here it is in a handy function...**

```
repeat () {
    seq  -f $1 -s '' $2; echo
}
```

Which you can call like this...

```
repeat "#" 10
```

**NOTE:** If you're repeating `#` then the quotes are important!

Comment: This gives me `seq: format ‘#’ has no % directive`.  `seq` is for numbers, not strings.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/seq-invocation.html

Comment: Ah, so I was using the BSD version of seq found on OS X. I'll update the answer. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using seq from GNU coreutils.

Comment: @JohnB: BSD `seq` is being _cleverly repurposed_ here to replicate _strings_: the format string passed to `-f` - normally used to format the _numbers_ being generated - contains only the string to replicate here so that the output contains copies of that string only. Unfortunately, GNU `seq` insists on the presence of a _number format_ in the format string, which is the error you're seeing.

Comment: Nicely done; also works with _multi_-characters strings. Please use `"$1"` (double quotes), so you can also pass in characters such as `'*'` and strings with embedded whitespace. Finally, if you want to be able to use `%`, you have to _double_ it (otherwise `seq` will think it's part of a format specification such as `%f`); using `"${1//%/%%}"` would take care of that. Since (as you mention) you're using _BSD_ `seq`, this _will work on BSD-like OSs in general_ (e.g., FreeBSD) - by contrast, it _won't work on Linux_, where _GNU_ `seq` is used.

Comment: Between `-f` and `"#"`, the space is _not_ required, because the option-argument is _nonempty_. It _is_ required after `-s`, because it's _technically_ impossible to pass the empty string as an option-argument by directly adjoining it to `-s`: the _shell_ removes the quotes from string `-s''` before passing it to `seq`, so `seq` would only see `-s`. `#` is not the only character that needs quoting - any of the so-called shell metacharacters and `*` do as well; best to simply always quote.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Unicode characters (box drawing characters in my case). `BD_H="\xE2\x94\x80"; repeat "${BD_H}" 20` renders 20 spaces.

Comment: Gives me error: `seq: invalid format string: `#'`

Answer (score 28):

Here's two interesting ways:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ yes = | head -10 | paste -s -d '' -
==========
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ yes = | head -10 | tr -d "\n"
==========ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Note these two are subtly different - The `paste` method ends in a new line.  The `tr` method does not.

Comment: Nicely done; please note that _BSD_ `paste` inexplicably requires `-d '\0'` for specifying an empty delimiter, and fails with `-d ''` - `-d '\0'` should work wit all POSIX-compatible `paste` implementations and indeed works with _GNU_ `paste` too.

Comment: Similar in spirit, with fewer outboard tools: `yes | mapfile -n 100 -C 'printf = \#' -c 1`

Comment: @bishop: While your command indeed creates one fewer subshell, it is still slower for higher repeat counts, and for lower repeat counts the difference probably doesn't matter; the exact threshold is probably both hardware- and OS-dependent, e.g., on my OSX 10.11.5 machine this answer is already faster at 500; try `time yes = | head -500 | paste -s -d '\0' -; time yes | mapfile -n 500 -C 'printf = \#' -c 1`.
More importantly, however: if you're using `printf` anyway, you may as well go with the both simpler and more efficient approach from the accepted answer: `printf '%.s=' $(seq 500)`

Answer (score 18):

There is no simple way. Avoid loops using `printf` and substitution.

```sh
str=$(printf "%40s")
echo ${str// /rep}
# echoes "rep" 40 times.
```

Comment: Nice, but only performs reasonably with small repeat counts. Here's a function wrapper that can be invoked as `repl = 100`, for instance (doesn't output a trailing `\n`): `repl() { local ts=$(printf "%${2}s"); printf %s "${ts// /$1}"; }`

Comment: @mklement0 Nice of you to provide function versions of both solutions, +1 on both!

Comment: A great solution that doesn't involve external programs. I would use `printf -v str …` instead of `str=$(printf …)` to avoid invoking a subshell, though. And for a general solution, I would use `printf "%s" "${str// /rep}"` instead of `echo`, because `printf` is more robust and doesn't choke on strings starting with `-` like `echo` does.

Answer (score 15):

The question was about how to do it with `echo`:

```
echo -e ''$_{1..100}'\b='
```

This will will do exactly the same as `perl -E 'say "=" x 100'` but with `echo` only.

Comment: Now that is unusual, if you don't ming extra space-backspaces in it..
or clean it up using:   echo -e $_{1..100}'\b=' | col

Comment: [Bad idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58779680/68587) This will fail if `$_1`, `$_2`, or any other of the hundred variables have values.

Comment: @JohnKugelman echo $( set --; eval echo -e \${{1..100}}'\\b=' )

Answer (score 13):

A pure Bash way with no `eval`, no subshells, no external tools, no brace expansions (i.e., you can have the number to repeat in a variable):

If you're given a variable `n` that expands to a (non-negative) number and a variable `pattern`, e.g.,

```
$ n=5
$ pattern=hello
$ printf -v output '%*s' "$n"
$ output=${output// /$pattern}
$ echo "$output"
hellohellohellohellohello
```

You can make a function with this:

```
repeat() {
    # $1=number of patterns to repeat
    # $2=pattern
    # $3=output variable name
    local tmp
    printf -v tmp '%*s' "$1"
    printf -v "$3" '%s' "${tmp// /$2}"
}
```

With this set:

```
$ repeat 5 hello output
$ echo "$output"
hellohellohellohellohello
```

---

For this little trick we're using `printf` quite a lot with:

- `-v varname`: instead of printing to standard output, `printf` will put the content of the formatted string in variable `varname`.
- '%*s': `printf` will use the argument to print the corresponding number of spaces. E.g., `printf '%*s' 42` will print 42 spaces.
- Finally, when we have the wanted number of spaces in our variable, we use a parameter expansion to replace all the spaces by our pattern: `${var// /$pattern}` will expand to the expansion of `var` with all the spaces replaced by the expansion of `$pattern`.

---

You can also get rid of the `tmp` variable in the `repeat` function by using indirect expansion:

```
repeat() {
    # $1=number of patterns to repeat
    # $2=pattern
    # $3=output variable name
    printf -v "$3" '%*s' "$1"
    printf -v "$3" '%s' "${!3// /$2}"
}
```

Comment: Interesting variation to pass the variable name in. While this solution is fine for repeat counts up to around 1,000 (and thus probably fine for most real-life applications, if I were to guess), it gets very slow for higher counts (see next comment).

Comment: It seems that `bash`'s global string replacement operations in the context of parameter expansion (`${var//old/new}`) are particularly slow: excruciatingly slow in bash `3.2.57`, and slow in bash `4.3.30`, at least on my OSX 10.10.3 system on a 3.2 Ghz Intel Core i5 machine: With a count of 1,000, things are slow (`3.2.57`) / fast (`4.3.30`): 0.1 / 0.004 seconds. Increasing the count to 10,000 yields strikingly different numbers:
 `repeat 10000 = var` takes around 80 seconds(!) in bash `3.2.57`, and around 0.3 seconds in bash `4.3.30` (much faster than on `3.2.57`, but still slow).

Answer (score 11):

If you want POSIX-compliance and consistency across different implementations of `echo` and `printf`, and/or shells other than just `bash`:

```
seq(){ n=$1; while [ $n -le $2 ]; do echo $n; n=$((n+1)); done ;} # If you don't have it.

echo $(for each in $(seq 1 100); do printf "="; done)
```

...will produce the same output as `perl -E 'say "=" x 100'` just about everywhere.

Comment: The problem is that `seq` is not a POSIX utility (though BSD and Linux systems have implementations of it) - you can do POSIX shell arithmetic with a `while` loop instead, as in @Xennex81's answer (with `printf "="`, as you correctly suggest, rather than `echo -n`).

Comment: Oops, you're quite right. Things like that just slip past me sometimes as that standard makes no f'ing sense. `cal` is POSIX. `seq` is not. Anyway, rather than rewrite the answer with a while loop (as you say, that's already in other answers) I'll add a RYO function. More educational that way ;-).

Comment: Warning: `seq` does not work properly for zero iterations. `seq 0` results in 2 iterations. `seq 0 0` results in 1 iteration. `seq 0 1` results in 2 iterations again.

Answer (score 11):

Another mean to repeat an arbitrary string n times:

Pros:

- Works with POSIX shell.
- Output can be assigned to a variable.
- Repeats any string.
- Very fast even with very large repeats.

Cons:

- Requires Gnu Core Utils's `yes` command.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/sh
to_repeat='='
repeat_count=80
yes "$to_repeat" | tr -d '\n' | head -c "$repeat_count"
```

With an ANSI terminal and US-ASCII characters to repeat. You can use an ANSI CSI escape sequence. It is the fastest way to repeat a character.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

char='='
repeat_count=80
printf '%c\e[%db' "$char" "$repeat_count"
```

Or statically:

Print a line of 80 times `=`:

`printf '=\e[80b\n'`

Limitations:

- Not all terminals understands the `repeat_char` ANSI CSI sequence.
- Only US-ASCII or single-byte ISO characters can be repeated.
- Repeat stops at last column, so you can use a large value to fill a whole line regardless of terminal width.
- The repeat is only for display. Capturing output into a shell variable will not expand the `repeat_char` ANSI CSI sequence into the repeated character.

Comment: Minor note - REP (CSI b) should wrap around normally if the terminal is in wrapping mode.

Answer (score 10):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  OFS = "="
  NF = 100
  print
}
```

Or

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  while (z++ < 100) printf "="
}
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/9524a901324ab8535597/misc/reddit.sh#L20-L26)

Comment: Nicely done; this is POSIX-compliant and reasonably fast even with high repeat counts, while also supporting multi-character strings. Here's the shell version: `awk 'BEGIN { while (c++ < 100) printf "=" }'`.
Wrapped into a parameterized shell function (invoke as `repeat 100 =`, for instance): `repeat() { awk -v count="$1" -v txt=".$2" 'BEGIN { txt=substr(txt, 2); while (i++ < count) printf txt }'; }`.
(The dummy `.` prefix char and complementary `substr` call are needed to work around a bug in BSD `awk`, where passing a variable value that _starts_ with `=` breaks the command.)

Comment: The `NF = 100` solution is very clever (though to get 100 `=`, you must use `NF = 101`). The caveats are that it crashes BSD `awk` (but it's very fast with `gawk` and even faster with `mawk`), and that
POSIX discusses neither _assigning_ to `NF`, nor use of fields in `BEGIN` blocks.
You can make it work in BSD `awk` as well with a slight tweak: `awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "="; $101=""; print }'` (but curiously, in BSD `awk` that isn't faster than the loop solution).
As a parameterized shell solution: `repeat() { awk -v count="$1" -v txt=".$2" 'BEGIN { OFS=substr(txt, 2); $(count+1)=""; print }'; }`.

Comment: Note to users - The NF=100 trick causes a segment fault on older awk. The `original-awk` is the name under Linux of the older awk similar to BSD's awk, which has also been reported to crash, if you want to try this. Note that crashing is usually the first step toward finding an exploitable bug. This answer is so promoting insecure code.

Comment: Note to users - `original-awk` is non standard and not recommended

Comment: An alternative to the first code snippet can be `awk NF=100 OFS='=' <<< ""` (using `bash` and `gawk`)

Comment: @user2350426 : I believe this happens because original awk was limited to 99 fields per line (.. and this is annoying in a lot of cases :( )

Answer (score 10):

Here's what I use to print a line of characters across the screen in linux (based on terminal/screen width)

## Print "=" across the screen:

```sh
printf '=%.0s' $(seq 1 $(tput cols))
```

**Explanation:**

Print an equal sign as many times as the given sequence:

```sh
printf '=%.0s' #sequence
```

Use the output of a command (this is a bash feature called Command Substitution):

```
$(example_command)
```

Give a sequence, I've used 1 to 20 as an example. In the final command the tput command is used instead of 20:

```sh
seq 1 20
```

Give the number of columns currently used in the terminal:

```sh
tput cols
```

Answer (score 6):

**Another bash solution using printf and tr**

*nb. before I begin:*

- Do we need another answer? *Probably not.*
- Is this answer here already? *Can't see it, so here goes.*

Use the leading-zero-padding feature of `printf` and convert the zeroes using `tr`.  This avoids any `{1..N}` generator:

```
$ printf '%040s' | tr '0' '='
========================================
```

To set the width to 'N' characters and customise the char printed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
N=40
C='-'
printf "%0${N}s" | tr '0' "${C}"
```

For large N, this is quite a bit more performant than the generator;  On my machine (bash 3.2.57):

```
$ time printf '=%.0s' {1..1000000}         real: 0m2.580s
$ time printf '%01000000s' | tr '0' '='    real: 0m0.577s
```

Answer (score 5):

In bash 3.0 or higher

```
for i in {1..100};do echo -n =;done
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess the original purpose of the question was to do this just with the shell's built-in commands. So `for` loops and `printf`s would be legitimate, while `rep`, `perl`, and also `jot` below would not. Still, the following command

```
jot -s "/" -b "\\" $((COLUMNS/2))
```

for instance, prints a window-wide line of `\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/`

Comment: Nicely done; this works well even with high repeat counts (while also supporting multi-character strings).
To better illustrate the approach, here's the equivalent of the OP's command: `jot -s '' -b '=' 100`.
The caveat is that while BSD-like platforms, including OSX, come with `jot`, _Linux distros do not_.

Comment: Thanks, I like your use of -s '' even better. I've changed my scripts.

Comment: On recent *Debian*-based systems, `apt install athena-jot` would provide `jot`.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, in bash [brace expansion](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) precedes [parameter expansion](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), so `{m,n}` ranges can only contain literals. [`seq`](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#seq-invocation) and [`jot`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=jot&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) provide clean solutions but aren't fully portable from one system to another, even if you're using the same shell on each. (Though `seq` is increasingly available; e.g., [in FreeBSD 9.3 and higher](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=seq&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).) [`eval`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/eval.1posix.html) and other forms of indirection always work but are somewhat inelegant.

Fortunately, bash [supports C-style for loops](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) (with arithmetic expressions only). So here's a concise "pure bash" way:

```
repecho() { for ((i=0; i<$1; ++i)); do echo -n "$2"; done; echo; }
```

This takes the number of repetitions as the first argument and the string to be repeated (which may be a single character, as in the problem description) as the second argument. `repecho 7 b` outputs `bbbbbbb` (terminated by a newline).

[Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson) gave [essentially this solution four years ago in his excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3213995/1038860) to [Creating string of repeated characters in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211891/shell-script-create-string-of-repeated-characters). My function body differs slightly from the code there:

- Since the focus here is on repeating a single character and the shell is bash, it's probably safe to use `echo` instead of `printf`. And I read the problem description in this question as expressing a preference to print with `echo`. The above function definition works in bash and [ksh93](http://kornshell.org/). Although `printf` is more portable (and should usually be used for this sort of thing), `echo`'s syntax is arguably more readable.

  Some shells' `echo` builtins interpret `-` by itself as an option--even though the usual meaning of `-`, to use stdin for input, is nonsensical for `echo`. [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/) does this. And there definitely exist `echo`s that don't recognize `-n`, as [it is not standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html). (Many Bourne-style shells don't accept C-style for loops at all, thus their `echo` behavior needn't be considered..)
- Here the task is to print the sequence; [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211891/shell-script-create-string-of-repeated-characters), it was to assign it to a variable.

If `$n` is the desired number of repetitions and you don't have to reuse it, and you want something even shorter:

```
while ((n--)); do echo -n "$s"; done; echo
```

`n` must be a variable--this way doesn't work with positional parameters. `$s` is the text to be repeated.

Comment: Strongly avoid doing loop versions. `printf "%100s" | tr ' ' '='` is optimal.

Comment: Good background info and kudos for packaging the functionality as a function, which works in `zsh` as well, incidentally. The echo-in-a-loop approach works well for smaller repeat counts, but for larger ones there are POSIX-compliant alternatives based on _utilities_, as evidenced by @Slomojo's comment.

Comment: Adding parentheses around your shorter loop preserves the value of n without affecting the echos: `(while ((n--)); do echo -n "$s"; done; echo)`

Comment: use printf instead of echo! it is way more portable (echo -n can work only on some systems). see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#65819 (one of Stephane Chazelas's awesome answer)

Comment: @OlivierDulac The question here is about bash. No matter what operating system you are running, *if you are using bash on it*, bash has an `echo` builtin that supports `-n`. The spirit of what you are saying is absolutely correct. `printf` should almost always be preferred to `echo`, at least in non-interactive use. But I don't think it was in any way inappropriate or misleading to give an `echo` answer to a question that asked for one *and that gave enough information to know that it would work*. Please note also that support for `((n--))` (without a `$`) is itself not guaranteed by POSIX.

Comment: @EliahKagan I never said it was innapropriate or misleading to give an echo answer, I warn that we (all) should stick to using printf insterad of echo, as printf is more portable (+ it avoids lots of side effects depending on the beginning of the thing echo'ed (minuses, etc), see stephane's answer). + that way the answer is not limited to bash-and-similar shells (btw, OP said bash but could have meant "shell")

Answer (score 4):

A more elegant alternative to the proposed Python solution could be:

```sh
python -c 'print "="*(1000)'
```

Answer (score 3):

Python is ubiquitous and works the same everywhere.

```
python -c "import sys; print('*' * int(sys.argv[1]))" "=" 100
```

Character and count are passed as separate parameters.

Comment: I think this was the intent here `python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv[1] * int(sys.argv[2]))" "=" 100`

Comment: @loevborg isn't that little bit far-fetched?

Answer (score 3):

Simplest is to use this one-liner in csh/tcsh:

```
printf "%50s\n" '' | tr '[:blank:]' '[=]'
```

---

Comment: or bash as printf "%50s\n" " "|tr ' ' "="

Answer (score 2):

```
repeat() {
    # $1=number of patterns to repeat
    # $2=pattern
    printf -v "TEMP" '%*s' "$1"
    echo ${TEMP// /$2}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the longer version of what Eliah Kagan was espousing:

```
while [ $(( i-- )) -gt 0 ]; do echo -n "  "; done
```

Of course you can use printf for that as well, but not really to my liking:

```
printf "%$(( i*2 ))s"
```

This version is Dash compatible:

```
until [ $(( i=i-1 )) -lt 0 ]; do echo -n "  "; done
```

with i being the initial number.

Comment: In bash and with a positive n: `while (( i-- )); do echo -n "  "; done` works.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use GNU seq and remove all numbers and newlines it generates:

```
seq -f'#%.0f' 100 | tr -d '\n0123456789'
```

This command prints the `#` character 100 times.

Comment: No need for the .f: `echo $(seq -f'#' 100 | tr -d '\n')`

Answer (score 2):

Not to pile-on, but another pure-Bash approach takes advantage of `${//}` substitution of arrays:

```
$ arr=({1..100})
$ printf '%s' "${arr[@]/*/=}"
====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

here's an `awk`-based repeater that's

- `fully POSIX-complaint`,
- `variable-length-friendly`,

> **completely** `loop-less (in fact, doesn't even have to spend time calculating the desired length unless you wanna customize it)`, and

- `non-awk-variant specific` ::

.

```
jot 15 | mawk2 'NF += OFS = $_'   

11
222
3333
44444
555555
6666666
77777777
888888888
9999999999
1010101010101010101010
111111111111111111111111
12121212121212121212121212
1313131313131313131313131313
141414141414141414141414141414
15151515151515151515151515151515
```

or just repeat the last one :

```
jot - 1 25 3 |

mawk2 'NF=NR^(OFS=$NF)^_' FS= 

1
44
777
10000
133333
1666666
19999999
222222222
2555555555
```

…… or repeat `ASCII punctuation` symbols  with a curvature ?

```
jot  -c  -  34 126 | gtr -cd '[:punct:]\n' |
nonEmpty           | rs -C'8' 0 2 |gtr -d '8' | 

mawk2 'NF+=_*(OFS=__=$NF)+int(NR*(1+sin(log(NR))))' FS='^$' 

"#"#
$%$%$%$%
&'&'&'&'&'&'
()()()()()()()()
*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+*+
,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
././././././././././././././
:;:;:;:;:;:;:;:;:;:;:;:;:;:;:;
<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=<=
>?>?>?>?>?>?>?>?>?>?>?>?>?>?>?>?>?>?
@[@[@[@[@[@[@[@[@[@[@[@[@[@[@[@[@[@[@[
\]\]\]\]\]\]\]\]\]\]\]\]\]\]\]\]\]\]\]\]
^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_
`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{`{
|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}|}
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

or perhaps make horizontal bar charts that resemble the normal distribution :

```
jot  -c - 34 126  | gtr -cd '0-9A-F\n' | 
 
mawk2 'NF && (NF+=_*(OFS=$NF)+exp(cos(NR/atan2(0,-1)))^4.1)'  FS='^$'

00
11111
22222222222222
333333333333333333333333333333333
444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555
66666666666666666666666666666666666666666666
7777777777777777777777
888888888
999
A
B
C
DD
EEEEEEE
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

… if you're a gambler at heart and wanna have it repeat something related to `euler e^pi` but also includes randomization, then

```
jot 20 | 

mawk2 'NF=NR+_*(OFS=sprintf("%.f",((NR*rand()*4))*exp(atan2(0,-1))))'
```

|

```
1
2111
35252
4220220220
5177177177177
6405405405405405
7543543543543543543
8649649649649649649649
9503503503503503503503503
10555555555555555555
11669669669669669669669669669669
12110110110110110110110110110110110
13917917917917917917917917917917917917
141188118811881188118811881188118811881188118811881188
1510151015101510151015101510151015101510151015101510151015
16521521521521521521521521521521521521521521521
17900900900900900900900900900900900900900900900900
1866666666666666666
19159159159159159159159159159159159159159159159159159159
20182182182182182182182182182182182182182182182182182182182
```

…. or straight up letters repeating based on something that's correlated with golden ratio but not the same :

```
jot  -c  -  34 126  | gtr -cd 'A-Za-z\n' |shuf | shuf | 
rs -t -C= 0 3 | gtr -d '=' |  

mawk2 'NF && (NF=NR^(exp(1)/(1+sqrt(5)))+_*(OFS=$_ ($_=_)))'  FS='^$'
```

|

```
qfd
NUONUO
WEvWEv
sCRsCRsCR
LoVLoVLoVLoV
putputputput
SYjSYjSYjSYjSYj
XcQXcQXcQXcQXcQ
hGrhGrhGrhGrhGrhGr
IyAIyAIyAIyAIyAIyAIyA
lZalZalZalZalZalZalZa
FMJFMJFMJFMJFMJFMJFMJFMJ
mwTmwTmwTmwTmwTmwTmwTmwT
DenDenDenDenDenDenDenDenDen
PHPHPHPHPHPHPHPHPH
iziziziziziziziziziz
```

…..just the last letter

```
 jot  -c  -  34 126  | gtr -cd 'A-Za-z\n' |shuf | shuf | 
 rs -t -C= 0 2 | gtr -d '=' |  

 mawk2 'NF && (NF=NR^(exp(1.1)/(1+sqrt(5)))+_*(OFS=$NF))'  FS=
```

.

```
l
A
kii
GIII
znnnn
fFFFFF
aHHHHHH
sSSSSSS
jooooooo
pTTTTTTTT
bDDDDDDDDD
Yvvvvvvvvvv
MCCCCCCCCCC
WBBBBBBBBBBB
JXXXXXXXXXXXX
mNNNNNNNNNNNNN
deeeeeeeeeeeee
xQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
thhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
yOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
Puuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
qRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
rLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL
VKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK
wUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU
ZEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

…and last but not least, fully `UTF-8` friendly, even emojis :
|

It starts to slowdown when the reps needed is above `100 million` or so, but short of that, this can be somewhat handy for essentially matching the convenience of languages with dedicated string repeat operators like `python ( * )` or `perl ( x )`

> beware though : **`it's as dangerous as it is efficacious :`**

```
jot - 1 90 8  | 

mawk2 '(OFS="")(NF+=\
        ((sqrt(NR)))^(20.5/6.0625\
        )^sqrt(sqrt(log((OFS=$!!NF))^2)))' FS='^$' OFS= | 

mawk -Wi -- '{  print "\t", 8*(NR)-7,
                        length($0),
               sprintf("%.50s",$0) }'

 1 2 11
 9 9 999999999
 17 144 17171717171717171717171717171717171717171717171717
 25 954 25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525
 33 5146 33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
 41 23526 41414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141
 49 94378 49494949494949494949494949494949494949494949494949
 57 340432 57575757575757575757575757575757575757575757575757
 65 1124212 65656565656565656565656565656565656565656565656565
 73 3445508 73737373737373737373737373737373737373737373737373
 81 9904644 81818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181
 89 26930222 89898989898989898989898989898989898989898989898989
```

It can grow ***really*** rapidly if you only change the parameters a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in {1..100}
do
  echo -n '='
done
echo
```

Answer (score 1):

In case that you want to repeat a character n times being n a VARIABLE number of times depending on, say, the length of a string you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
vari='AB'
n=$(expr 10 - length $vari)
echo 'vari equals.............................: '$vari
echo 'Up to 10 positions I must fill with.....: '$n' equal signs'
echo $vari$(perl -E 'say "=" x '$n)
```

It displays:

```
vari equals.............................: AB  
Up to 10 positions I must fill with.....: 8 equal signs  
AB========
```

Comment: `length` won't work with `expr`, you probably meant `n=$(expr 10 - ${#vari})`; however, it's simpler and more efficient to use Bash's arithmetic expansion: `n=$(( 10 - ${#vari} ))`. Also, at the core of your answer is the very Perl approach that the OP is looking for a Bash  _alternative_ to.

Answer (score 1):

```
function repeatString()
{
    local -r string="${1}"
    local -r numberToRepeat="${2}"

    if [[ "${string}" != '' && "${numberToRepeat}" =~ ^[1-9][0-9]*$ ]]
    then
        local -r result="$(printf "%${numberToRepeat}s")"
        echo -e "${result// /${string}}"
    fi
}
```

Sample runs

```
$ repeatString 'a1' 10 
a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1a1

$ repeatString 'a1' 0 

$ repeatString '' 10
```

Reference lib at: https://github.com/gdbtek/linux-cookbooks/blob/master/libraries/util.bash

Answer (score 1):

> How could I do this with echo?

You can do this with `echo` if the `echo` is followed by `sed`:

```
echo | sed -r ':a s/^(.*)$/=\1/; /^={100}$/q; ba'
```

Actually, that `echo` is unnecessary there.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a bit more complicated, and probably not perfect, but for those looking to output large numbers, I was able to do around 10 million in 3 seconds.

```
repeatString(){
    # argument 1: The string to print
    # argument 2: The number of times to print
    stringToPrint=$1
    length=$2

    # Find the largest integer value of x in 2^x=(number of times to repeat) using logarithms
    power=`echo "l(${length})/l(2)" | bc -l`
    power=`echo "scale=0; ${power}/1" | bc`

    # Get the difference between the length and 2^x
    diff=`echo "${length} - 2^${power}" | bc`

    # Double the string length to the power of x
    for i in `seq "${power}"`; do 
        stringToPrint="${stringToPrint}${stringToPrint}"
    done

    #Since we know that the string is now at least bigger than half the total, grab however many more we need and add it to the string.
    stringToPrint="${stringToPrint}${stringToPrint:0:${diff}}"
    echo ${stringToPrint}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is to use this one-liner in bash:

```
seq 10 | xargs -n 1 | xargs -I {} echo -n  ===\>;echo
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Most existing solutions all depend on `{1..10}` syntax support of the shell, which is `bash`- and `zsh`- specific, and doesn't work in `tcsh` or OpenBSD's [`ksh`](http://mdoc.su/o/ksh.1) and most non-bash `sh`.

The following should work on OS X and all *BSD systems in any shell; in fact, it can be used to generate a whole matrix of various types of decorative space:

```
$ printf '=%.0s' `jot 64` | fold -16
================
================
================
================$
```

Sadly, we don't get a trailing newline; which can be fixed by an extra `printf '\n'` after the fold:

```
$ printf "=%.0s" `jot 64` | fold -16 ; printf "\n"
================
================
================
================
$
```

References:

- http://mdoc.su/-/printf.1
- http://mdoc.su/-/jot.1
- http://mdoc.su/-/fold.1

Answer (score 1):

My proposal (accepting **variable** values for n):

```
n=100
seq 1 $n | xargs -I {} printf =
```

Comment: in what way is your xargs different from sed

Comment: this was surprisingly slow, but did give me the variable for both the length and the character being printed that I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly longer version, but if you have to use pure Bash for some reason, you can use a while loop with an incrementing variable:

```
n=0; while [ $n -lt 100 ]; do n=$((n+1)); echo -n '='; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use terminal escape sequences to *repeat the preceding character n times (REP)* here for the length of the line

```bash
printf "a\e[$((COLUMNS-1));b"
```

If COLUMNS is not available in your bash script initialize with

```
# if stdout is attached to a terminal
if [[ -t 1 ]]; then
# initialize winsize feature in bash
shopt -s checkwinsize
# and wait until it has initialized
while [[ -z “${COLUMNS:-}" ]]; do sleep 0.1; done;
fi
```

Or use `tput cols`.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer for `zsh`

The question is tagged `bash`; for completeness I'll add what is in my opinion the cleanest option using `zsh`:

```bash
$ echo ${(l[4][=])}

====
```

Add flag `(p)` to provide the parameters as variables:

```bash
$ n=4; ch='='
$ echo ${(pl[$n][$ch])}

====
```

#### Explanation

- `${(l[w][c])str}` left-pads parameter named *str* to length *w* using char *c*
- `${(l[w][c])}` left-pads an empty string
- adding flag `(p)`, `${(pl...)}`, will enable parameter expansion for the flag arguments, so we can use `$n` and `$ch`

Answer (score 0):

```
n=5; chr='x'; chr_string='';
for (( i=0; $i<$n; i++ ))
do
    chr_string=$chr_string$chr
done
echo -n "$chr_string"
```

Works for...
n=integer (inclusive of zero and negetive).
chr=printable and white space (space and tab).

Comment: The best answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without invoking an external command.
First you prepend 0 to a 0 until it counts a len of 100, then you replace zero with the character you want.

```
LEN=100
foo="$(builtin printf "%0${LEN}d" 0)"
echo "${foo//0/=}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It was very briefly mentioned above, the simplest way is with '\e[Nb' escape sequence. It prints the previous character 1+N times:

```
$ printf '↑\e[4b\n'
↑↑↑↑↑
```

And stops at the end of the line:

```
$ printf '#\e[10000000b\n'
##########################################################################
```

Use this function to choose the character ($1) and the number of times to print it ($2). The newline (\n) at the end is optional...

```
$ rep (){ printf -- "$1\e[$(($2-1))b\n"; }
```

If you want to fill to the end of the line, in case the number of times is not passed:

```
$ rep (){ printf -- "$1\e[$((${2:-1000}-1))b\n"; }

$ rep ↑ 5
↑↑↑↑↑
$ rep \#
##########################################################################
```

Note that the number of times will match from 2 onwards, maybe this matter in some script at some point, most likely never...

```
$ rep \@ 2
@@
$ rep \@ 1
@@
$ rep \@ 0
@
```

Limitations:

- stops at the end of the line
- does not work with escape sequences

To overcome this, you can use this other method already mentioned, i just summarized it in the function below. Note that this way you can use escape sequences for color, tab or new line, for example, repeat as many times you want, and also use "any" string, beyond just 1 character.

```
$ rep (){ local a; printf -v a %$2s; printf -- "${a// /$1}"; }
```

Silly example:

```
$ rep "$(rep '\U1F9A5\t' 7)\n\n" 2
              

              

$
```

Some info on escape sequences:
https://embedded.fel.cvut.cz/sites/default/files/kurzy/ETC/ESP_TERMINAL/ESPTerm_reference.pdf

https://git.suckless.org/st/commit/e8392b282c2eaa28725241a9612804fb55113da4.html

Comment: Don't put variables inside the format string for printf. Instead of `printf -- "$1\e[$(($2-1))b\n"`, please write `printf '%s\e[%ub\n' "$1" $(($2-1))` (Note you don't need `--` when the format string does not start with a dash.)

Answer (score 0):

When repeat counts grow beyond 10-million or so, shortcomings of the standard doubling method really start to amplify. String squaring is the way to go -

> **`"=" x 8,589,934,592 (2^33)`**

Using 7 rounds of the `while()` loop, `awk` generated a single string of nearly 8.6 ***billion*** copies of the equals (`=`) sign in just `0.806 secs` (and this is the speed of user-level scripting not any built-in operator).

-
( time (  echo '= 8589934592' | mawk2 '

```
     function ______(__,_) {

         printf("\t while(...) loop-# %-3d :: NF == %5d | \"=\" x %-12d \n",
              (__ = +__)<!__ ? -__:__, NF, +_ ? _ : _ = length()\
                 ) >("/dev/"(__<!__ || __ ? "stdout" : "null"))
         fflush()
         return _
      }
      BEGIN { CONVFMT = "%.250g" } { 

            ___ = +$NF
          _____ = _ = (_ = $--NF) (_)_
           _=__ = NF -= NF
            ___ = (_ += ++_)^(_+_+_)^_
              _ = _____
          _____ = ".."

         while((____=______(++__, length(_))) * ____ <= ___)
             gsub(_____,_,_) 

     }' ) )
```

---

```
 ( echo '= 8589934592' | mawk2 ; )  
 0.18s user 0.63s system 99% cpu 0.806 total
```

---

```
     while(...) loop-# 1   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 3            
     while(...) loop-# 2   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 4            
     while(...) loop-# 3   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 8            
     while(...) loop-# 4   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 32           
     while(...) loop-# 5   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 512          
     while(...) loop-# 6   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 131072       
     while(...) loop-# 7   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 8589934592
```

At speeds like that, it's usually faster to just use a few default parameters and then `substr()` out the precise count desired.

One could also use some form of doubling at the start to skip ahead a few loops :

```
( echo '= 8589934592' | mawk2 ; )  

 0.18s user 0.62s system 99% cpu 0.803 total

     while(...) loop-# 1   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 32           
     while(...) loop-# 2   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 512          
     while(...) loop-# 3   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 131072       
     while(...) loop-# 4   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 8589934592
```

One can also modify the initial # of copies as well as fine-tune the aggressiveness of `regex` replacements to

> Start with **8** copies, `regex` replacement :: `gsub("...",_,_)`

```
 0.00s user 0.00s system 81% cpu 0.005 total

 while(...) loop-# 1   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 8            
 while(...) loop-# 2   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 18           
 while(...) loop-# 3   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 108          
 while(...) loop-# 4   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 3888         
 while(...) loop-# 5   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 5038848
```

> Start with **16** copies, `regex` replacement :: `gsub("..",_,_)`

```
 0.00s user 0.00s system 86% cpu 0.007 total

 while(...) loop-# 1   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 16           
 while(...) loop-# 2   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 128          
 while(...) loop-# 3   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 8192         
 while(...) loop-# 4   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 33554432
```

> Start with **12** copies, `regex` replacement :: `gsub("...",_,_)`

```
 0.28s user 0.96s system 99% cpu 1.244 total

 while(...) loop-# 1   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 12           
 while(...) loop-# 2   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 48           
 while(...) loop-# 3   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 768          
 while(...) loop-# 4   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 196608       
 while(...) loop-# 5   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 12884901888
```

> Start with **16** copies, `regex` replacement :: `gsub("....",_,_)`

```
 0.36s user 1.26s system 99% cpu 1.631 total

 while(...) loop-# 1   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 16           
 while(...) loop-# 2   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 64           
 while(...) loop-# 3   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 1024         
 while(...) loop-# 4   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 262144       
 while(...) loop-# 5   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 17179869184
```

Or if you like to keep it clean powers of 10 (or all 9s) :

> Start with **10** copies, `regex` replacement :: `gsub(".",_,_)`

```
 0.00s user 0.01s system 89% cpu 0.015 total

 while(...) loop-# 1   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 10           
 while(...) loop-# 2   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 100          
 while(...) loop-# 3   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 10000        
 while(...) loop-# 4   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 100000000
```

> Start with **9** copies, `regex` replacement :: `gsub(//,_,_)`

```
 0.00s user 0.01s system 86% cpu 0.016 total

 while(...) loop-# 1   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 9            
 while(...) loop-# 2   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 99           
 while(...) loop-# 3   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 9999         
 while(...) loop-# 4   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 99999999
```

> Start with **3** copies, `regex` replacement :: `gsub(//,"=" _,_)` - you could even generate perfectly prime lengths at every single loop :

```
 0.71s user 2.34s system 99% cpu 3.044 total

 while(...) loop-# 1   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 3            
 while(...) loop-# 2   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 19           
 while(...) loop-# 3   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 419          
 while(...) loop-# 4   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 176819       
 while(...) loop-# 5   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 31265489219 

          3: 3
         19: 19
        419: 419
     176819: 176819
31265489219: 31265489219
```

> Start with **7** copies, `regex` replacement :: `gsub(//,(_)_ "=",_)` and it yields a handful of Mersenne Primes -

```
 0.04s user 0.15s system 95% cpu 0.200 total

 while(...) loop-# 1   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 7            
 while(...) loop-# 2   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 127          
 while(...) loop-# 3   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 32767        
 while(...) loop-# 4   :: NF ==     0 | "=" x 2147483647
```

Answer (score -1):

```
printf -- '=%.0s' {1..100}
```

The double dash `--` means "End of command line flags", so don't try to parse what comes after command line options.

If you want to print the dash `-` character, rather than the `=` character, multiple times and don't include the double dash `--` this is what you'll get:

```
$ printf '-%.0s' {1..100}
bash: printf: -%: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

Why not create a one line function like this:

```
function repeat() { num="${2:-100}"; printf -- "$1%.0s" $(seq 1 $num); }
```

Then, you can call it like this:

```
$ repeat -
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

or like that:

```
$ repeat =
====================================================================================================
```

or like this:

```
$ repeat '*' 8
********
```