# Windows console: Print repeated string to file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, repeat

Is there a way I can port this:

```
printf '=%.0s' {1..100} > file.txt
```

from bash to the cmd console?

To see what the code above does look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash).

I can think of a few workarounds with variables and for-loops but I hoped for a quick and easy solution that doesn't require an the "-v" option set for the cmd in question (the shell is opened by `make` so as far as I know you can't specify the "-v" option).

Comment: I'm ashamed to say I'm not terribly familiar with bash. What does the code do?

Comment: I added what the explanation what the code should do.

Comment: Alright, string of one hundred equals signs with no terminating newline character. Got it. There's definitely a way to do this in batch, I just need to find the snippet...

Comment: @WorldSEnder Does it absolutely **have** to be the = symbol? For some reason, the snippet I'm using doesn't like displaying them, but I can do a - if that's acceptable.

Comment: It does not have to be displayed as long as it is written to the file, but yes, it has to be an `=`-symbol. Don't mind and submit it though, I may find a workaround myself.

Comment: You could `>file.txt echo ====================================================================================================`

Comment: @WorldSEnder What is this being used for? I've managed to display 100 = symbols to the command line, but if you open the file in a text editor, you can see that I achieved it by printing `.<backspace>=` 100 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to simulate `printf` with batch.  PowerShell does offer similar functionality using [composite strings](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/12/use-powershell-to-format-strings-with-composite-formatting.aspx) though.  So, invoking PowerShell, your `printf` command becomes this:

```
powershell -command "'='*100" > file.txt
```

Comment: Not quite what I want, but easily modifiable to that. You may want to read through bash's printf again :D

Comment: lol OK. Yeah, I just ssh'd into my Linux box to test your command and discovered how embarrassingly wrong that was. :)  Thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I'm having a hard time printing the = symbol, but otherwise, this prints 100 `-` characters and no terminating newline character. I'll keep looking to see if there's a workaround.

```
@echo off

(
    for /L %%A in (1,1,100) do (
        <nul set/p =-
    )
)>file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of thoroughness, here's another possibility.  It's a two-liner, though.  Still, if you're benchmarking, I think it'll have a speed advantage over the powershell solution.

```
set /p "=for(i=100;i--;)WSH.StdOut.Write('=')"<NUL>tmp.js
>file.txt cscript /nologo tmp.js && del tmp.js
```

Or, in for a penny, in for a pound I guess.  Create **repeat.js** as follows:

```
for (i=WSH.Arguments(1); i--; ) {
    WSH.StdOut.Write(WSH.Arguments(0));
}
```

Then call it as `cscript /nologo repeat.js "=" 100 >file.txt` whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

with a little trick, FBnerFP's answer does, what you want:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "x="
for /l %%i in (1,1,100) do set x=!x!=
echo %x%
```

Note: a `for`variable (`x` is a one-digit-name. `%variable` won't work.

Note: for use at the command prompt write `%i` instead of `%%i` in batch files

Comment: That requires having started the cmd with cmd -v, as explained this is not possible. Or I would have to create a bashscript to call, which seems like too much overhead for such a simple task... I'll consider it.

Comment: ahhmmm - no. Either `/v` or `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

Answer (score -1):

See `For /l`.

```
FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]
```

> The set is a sequence of numbers So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)

Comment: How does that help? echo will append a newline even when I append that to the file. Please explain a bit more

Comment: `>>` appends while `>` overwrites. If you don't specify your actual problem you won't get useful answers.