# I want to have a variable with only spaces in unix

Tags: ksh

I want a variable having 'n' spaces in it. How can i do it ?

Comment: Use a loop for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repeat a character in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash)

Comment: @Paul, assuming that the OP is using bash, then there's some good suggestions there, although most of the answers to that question aren't going to work in other shells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have able to do it by using typeset.

For ex :

```
typeset -L11 x="";
```

this will assign 11 spaces to the variable.

**Option    Operation**

**-Ln**

Left-justify. Remove leading spaces; if n is given, fill with spaces or truncate on right to length n.

**-Rn**

Right-justify. Remove trailing spaces; if n is given, fill with spaces or truncate on left to length n.

**-Zn**

If used with -R, add leading 0's instead of spaces if needed. If used with -L, strips leading 0's. By itself, acts the same as -RZ.

**-l**
Convert letters to lowercase.

**-u**
Convert letters to uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is to use this special `printf` format:

```
n=10

# assign n char length space to var
printf -v var "%*s" $n " "

# check length
echo "${#var}"
10
```

**PS:** If `printf -v` isn't available then use:

```
var=$(printf "%*s" $n " ")
```

Comment: Looks good - is that a bash-only thing or will it work on other POSIX shells?

Comment: On my OSX it worked using `/bin/sh` as well as `bash`

Comment: thanks anubhava. I got it now. I used typeset for it. Ex : typeset -L11 x="";

Comment: Using `typeset` I am getting `sh: typeset: -L: invalid option`

Comment: Anubhava- i am using ksh. can you try by adding this to the script #!/usr/bin/ksh

Comment: 1. Your question is not tagged as `ksh`. 2. `typeset` answer won't work with other shells. 3. Above `printf` solution works with `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh` and probably `sh` also.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function to return a given number of spaces:

```
n_spaces() { n=$1; while [ $((n--)) -gt 0 ]; do printf ' '; done; }
```

Then to assign to a variable, use `var=$(n_spaces 5)`.

Obviously there's a lot of ways you could do this using other tools/languages such as Perl:

```
n_spaces() { perl -se 'print " " x $x' -- -x="$1"; }
```

Comment: Thanks Tom Fenech. I got it now. I used typeset for it. Ex : typeset -L11 x="";

Comment: Also i will definitely try using perl with my shell scripting

Comment: You're welcome. If you have found your own solution to the problem, you should post it as an answer so that other people can use it in the future.

Comment: Hey Tom , can you answer this as well ------Example : 

Say i have 3 variables x=1,y=2,z=3.

I am adding to abc.dat file like below :

echo "${x}${y}${z}" >> abc.dat;

But file has content as :
1
2
3
meaning new lines are coming.
I want like this : 123 without new lines.