# bash: print x number of blank lines

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Sometimes I want to create lots of whitespace at once (slightly different than a specific character). I attempted to do this using a for loop, but I am only printing `\n` once with this implementation. Furthermore, the actual '\n' character is actually  printed instead of a blank line. What is a better way to do this?

```
for i in {1....100}
> do
>   echo "\n"
> done
```

Comment: So leave the "\n" off and just use echo with no parameters - echo automatically adds a linefeed unless you use the -n  option.

Comment: Also you should have `{1..100}` and not `{1....100}` because four dots doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repeat a character in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jerry commented you made a syntax error.

This seems to work :

```
for i in {1..100}
do
    echo "\n"
done
```

Comment: This apparently prints 100 lines with `\n` string.

Comment: This would work in most POSIX shells, just not `bash`.

Comment: `echo` should be enough not sure why you'd need `\n`

Comment: This is not working neither in ubuntu 16 nor macos mohave

Answer (score 13):

To print 5 blank lines:

```
yes '' | sed 5q
```

To print N blank lines:

```
yes '' | sed ${N}q
```

Comment: `head` is simpler than `sed`.

Comment: choroba@: I disagree.  'head -5' is 7 characters, 'sed 5q' is only 6.  Also, using sed reduces the number of tools you need to know.  With sed, there's no need for head.

Comment: Just because you can do anything in sed doesn't mean you should. Using `head` is less obscure

Answer (score 4):

- [Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) expects two dots, not any other number:

  ```
  $ echo {1....5}
  {1....5}
  $ echo {1..5}
  1 2 3 4 5
  ```

  That's why your loop was executed just once.
- If you want [`echo`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-echo) to interpret your escape sequences, you need to call it with `echo -e`.
- `echo` outputs a newline anyway, so `echo -e "\n"` prints *two* newlines. To prevent `echo` from printing a newline you have to use `echo -n`, and `echo -ne "\n"` is the same as just `echo`.
- You can print repeating characters, in this case a newline, like this:

  ```
  printf '\n%.0s' {1..100}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can abuse printf for that:

```
printf '\n%.s' {1..100}
```

This prints `\n` followed by a zero-length string 100 times (so effectively, `\n` 100 times).

One caveat of using brace expansion though is that you cannot use variables in it, unless you eval it:

```
count=100
eval "printf '\n%.s' {1..$count}"
```

To avoid the eval you can use a loop; it's slightly slower but shouldn't mater unless you need thousands of them:

```
count=100
for ((i=0; i<$count; i++)); do printf '\n'; done
```

NB: If you use the eval method, make sure you trust your count, else it's easy to inject commands into the shell:

```
$ count='1}; /bin/echo "Hello World ! " # '
$ eval "printf '\n%.s' {1..$count}"

Hello World !
```

One easy fix in Bash is to declare your variable as an integer (ex: `declare -i count`). Any attempts to pass something else than an number will fail. It may still be possible to trigger DOS attacks by passing very large values for the brace expansion, which may cause bash to trigger an OOM condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try either of the following

```
for i in {1..100}; do echo ; done
```

Or

```
for i in {1..100}
do 
    echo
done
```

Worked for Ubuntu 16LTS and MacOS X