# How can i do "-" * 60 for Unix command line

Tags: unix, ubuntu, command-line

If I want to print 60 dashes.

Somehow like

`echo "-" * 60`.

How can I do with this?
Thanks.

Comment: For bash [stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf "%*s" 60 "" | tr " " "-"
```

The printf command prints an empty string padded with spaces to fit a width of 60. Then tr converts the spaces to dashes.

This does not print a trailing newline. If you want one, add `;echo` to the end of the command.

Answer (score 1):

`printf '%s\n' $(dd if=/dev/zero count=60 status=none | tr '\000' '-')`