# How to repeat a dash (hyphen) in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, repeat

How can I repeat the character `-` n times in shell? I have read and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash), but this does not work for `-`. It throws error `invalid option`. Below is the exact command that I used:

```
printf '-%.0s' {1..100}
```

<sup>Original posted line: `printf '-%0.s' {1..100}`</sup>

I also tried escaping `-` by putting a `\` but in that case it repeats `\-` n times.

Comment: The title says "dash", but it's tagged with "bash". Which one do you mean?

Comment: @Kusalananda: The OP refers to the dash _character_ (`-`, ASCII / Unicode code point `0x2d`). (Strictly speaking, the character's name is _hyphen_, but in practice the two names are used interchangeably.)

Comment: @mklement0 Ah. Severe misunderstanding on my part. I've read too many question with badly mangled language lately...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This throws an error:

```
$ printf '-%.0s' {1..100}; echo ""
bash: printf: -%: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

This works fine under `bash`:

```
$ printf -- '-%.0s' {1..100}; echo ""
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For other shells, try:

```
printf -- '-%.0s' $(seq 100); echo ""
```

The problem was the `printf` expects that `-` starts an option.  As is common among Unix/POSIX utilities in this type of situation, `--` signals to `printf` to expect no more options.

Comment: +1. And this solution is good to remember, because it's not specific to printf; many utilities support `--` as a special flag meaning "no more options after this point".

Comment: Not just Linux utilities, it's a POSIX-specified utility convention. See Guideline 10 in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Very good.  Answer updated to mention POSIX. I checked [POSIX `printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) and, since it accepts no options, it makes no mention of accepting `--`.

Comment: Indeed. That said, the utility-guidelines section of POSIX indicates that deviations from the guidelines will be described in the OPTIONS section of a utility's individual documentation.

Answer (score 7):

[John1024's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38861956/45375) provides a generic solution that shows how to disambiguate options from operands for *all* POSIX-like utilities.

In the case at hand, the simplest solution is (works not only in `bash`, but also in `ksh` and `zsh`):

```
printf '%.0s-' {1..100}
```

Placing `%.0s` *before* the `-` avoids the issue of an initial `-` getting mistaken for an option.

Slightly optimized:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
printf '%.s-' {1..100}
```

---

<sup>[1] **`%.0s` is *in practice the most portable* form** (to be fully portable, you must also avoid the brace expansion, `{...}`).

**`%.s`**, the equivalent shorthand form, is **supported by `bash`, `ksh`, and `dash`, but *not* `zsh` <= v5.2** - even though it is [equally POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html#tag_05) : "The precision [the part after `.`] shall take the form of a  ( '.' ) followed by a decimal digit string; a null digit string is treated as zero."</sup>

<sup>As a **side note**: The question originally contained a benign (in Bash) typo that sparked a debate: `%0.s` instead of `%.0s`:  `%0.s` *should* effectively be the same as `%.0s`, and for that matter, the same as `%.s` and `%0.0s` (all effectively request: print a [minimum zero-width] field filled with a zero-length string), but *in practice isn't*: `zsh` <= v5.2 doesn't handle `%0.s` correctly (again, due to the `.s` part).

Similarly, the *GNU* `printf` *external-utility* implementation (`/usr/bin/printf`), as of GNU coreutils v8.24,  reports an *error* with `%0.s`, because it generally doesn't accept a field width of `0` with `s`: `invalid conversion specification` - this matters for lesser-known shells that don't provide `printf` as a *builtin*. Note that the BSD/OSX implementation does not have this problem.

Both `zsh`'s (<= v5.2) behavior with `%.s` and GNU `/usr/bin/printf`'s behavior with `%0s` are deviations from the POSIX spec that smell like bugs.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302687/is-it-a-bug-that-zsh-print-the-full-string-with-printf-s) asks about `zsh`'s behavior regarding `%.s`, and the bug has since been confirmed and [reported as  fixed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/302693/54804) via a [post-v5.2 commit](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/e1c745a0dca56afb9cfcace1ef59449152290188) that has yet to be released as of this writing.</sup>

Comment: If, as you comment, zsh and GNU printf (at least) fail (at the time you are writing this) with `%0.s` and/or `%.s` then both options are not portable and you should (if you act in a responsible way) not recommend them.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: There is no such recommendation in my answer. There _is_ a recommendation to use `%.0s` as the currently most portable form, _if_ portability is needed (incidental to this question, because, as stated, _all_ format-string variations work fine in `bash`). Beyond that, there is an analysis of differing behavior in real-world implementations and how they relate to the POSIX spec.

Comment: @mklement0 The statement `%0.s should effectively be the same as %.0s` is false. Your initial mistake (check edit 1) was to propose that `%0.s` was the solution. You have never said that that was wrong. Do it now.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: Saying that the statement is false without explaining _why_ is unhelpful. My answer _explains_ why they should be the same, so if you find fault in that reasoning, do tell us. `%0.s` works just fine in `bash`, `ksh`, and `dash`, due to the explained equivalence; it doesn't work in `zsh` <= 5.2 and GNU `/usr/bin/printf` due to (unrelated) bugs. However, because `%0.s` is not a good expression of the solution's intent (and started out as a typo by the OP, long since corrected) and _practically_ limits portability, I switched to `%.0s` (and only discuss `%0.s` in the _footnote_).

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop and number range:

```
for i in {1..10}; 
    do echo "-"; 
done
```

Or on a single line:

```
for i in {1..10}; 
    do echo -n "-"; 
done
```

which outputs `----------`.

**EDIT**: This was before your `printf` edit.

Comment: `echo -n` is explicitly non-POSIX-specified behavior. You might stay clear of it if trying to be portable. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html: "If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a backslash ( '\' ) character, the results are implementation-defined"

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Is `printf` a better alternative for that reason?

Comment: Yes. (See the APPLICATION USAGE section of the prior link).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a traditional `for` loop, as there is no need to spawn sub-processes or expand 100 arguments:

```
N=100
for((i = 0; i < $N; ++i)); do
  printf -
done
```

It is curious that `printf -%s` triggers "invalid option" but `printf -` does not. To perhaps be extra safe, you could do `printf %s -`.

Comment: Not really that curious. `-` is a completely valid argument, conventionally used to refer to stdin or stdout as appropriate to context, whereas `-x` sets an option flag.

Comment: No need for a `$` inside an arithmetic evaluation: `for((i = 0; i<N;i++)); do`

Comment: `printf '%.s-' {1..100}` involves _no_ subshells, because brace expansion is a shell feature, and `printf` is a Bash _builtin_. As such, combining the brace expansion with builtin `printf` is _not_ subject to the max. command-line length, but you're right that with large repeat counts there are alternatives that are both faster and especially more memory-efficient (but a _shell loop_ is _not_ the right tool for large repeat counts) - see [the answer the OP linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash).

Comment: @mklement0 Indeed, I was thinking of the solutions involving `perl`, `tr`, `head`, etc. with regard to the sub-process criticism. If `printf` were not a built-in, then the solution I posted would spawn 100 processes! And yes, my criticism with using `{1..N}` is that it requires O(N) space.

Comment: Got it - makes perfect sense. `/usr/bin/printf '-%.0s' {1..100}` still only involves 1 child process (to which a potentially very long list of arguments is passed), but with an external utility you do have to worry about the max. command-line length (as reported by `getconf ARG_MAX`).

Comment: In fact, `{1..N}` actually requires Ω(N log N) space because the size of each argument increases logarithmically...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `tput` along with `printf` to accomplish filling the terminal with an exact number of dashes, either drawing the line directly, or writing the line of dashes to a variable (say `line`) for repeated use, e.g. to write a screen width line of dashes to the variable `line`, you could do:

```
$ eval printf -v line '%.0s-' {1..$(tput cols)}
```

and then simply `echo "$line"` each time you need to draw the line. You can also write it directly to the screen with.

```
$ eval printf '%.0s-' {1..$(tput cols)}
```

(I'm not a huge fan of `eval`, but this is one use where you are guaranteed the result of the command cannot be harmful).

Answer (score 1):

This has been my goto for years... not AIX friendly though. Change the last character to change the repeating character which makes up the line

```
printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' _
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `jot` can do it, with no *bash*isms:

   ```
   jot -s '' -b - 100
   ```
2. `seq` too, but not as well, it needs a `tr`:

   ```
   seq -s- 100 | tr -d '[0-9]'
   ```

Comment: Given as `jot` is not a POSIX-specified tool, it's arguably every bit as nonportable as, well, bash. Exactly the same criticism goes for `seq`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, true... but there's no *POSIX* tag in the OP.