# Multiplying strings in bash script

Tags: string, bash, concatenation

I know that if I do `print ("f" + 2 * "o")` in python the output will be `foo`.

But how do I do the same thing in a bash script?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `bash` [`command substitution`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to be more portable across systems than to use a variant specific command.

```
$ myString=$(printf "%10s");echo ${myString// /m}           # echoes 'm' 10 times
mmmmmmmmmm

$ myString=$(printf "%10s");echo ${myString// /rep}         # echoes 'rep' 10 times
reprepreprepreprepreprepreprep
```

Wrapping it up in a more usable shell-function

```
repeatChar() {
    local input="$1"
    local count="$2"
    printf -v myString '%*s' "$count"
    printf '%s\n' "${myString// /$input}"
}

$ repeatChar str 10
strstrstrstrstrstrstrstrstrstr
```

Comment: Use `printf -v myString '%*s' "$count"` instead of `myString=$(...)`. And use `local` to mark your variables local (or drop the local variables and use the parameters directly).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Yup, it is a pretty old answer. Will make the change anyway!

Comment: You can simplify to `$ ${$(printf %10s)// /rep}`

Comment: @pjh: Fixed it, turned out to be a wrong edit

Comment: `repeatChar` works now.  Its handling of counts with leading zeros may be surprising to some though.  (`repeatChar str 09` fails with an `invalid octal number` error.)

Answer (score 6):

You could simply use loop

```
$ for i in {1..4}; do echo -n 'm'; done
mmmm
```

Answer (score 5):

That will do:

```
printf 'f'; printf 'o%.0s' {1..2}; echo
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861895/how-to-repeat-a-dash-in-shell) for explanations on the "multiplying" part.

Comment: I like this answer most, but I would rewrite it as: `printf -- "f%s\n" $(printf -- "o%.0s" {1..2})` . The downside is that it needs a subshell, but it does the job quite well.

Answer (score 2):

In bash you can use simple string indexing in a similar manner

```
#!/bin/bash
oos="oooooooooooooo"
n=2
printf "%c%s\n" 'f' ${oos:0:n}
```

output

```
foo
```

Another approach simply concatenates characters into a string

```
#!/bin/bash
n=2
chr=o
str=
for ((i = 0; i < n; i++)); do 
    str="$str$chr"
done
printf "f%s\n" "$str"
```

Output

```
foo
```

There are several more that can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **function** to loop a string for a **specific count** and use it in the
loop you are executing with dynamic length. **FYI** a different version of oter answers.

```
  line_break()
    {
        for i in `seq 0 ${count}`
        do
          echo -n "########################"
        done
    }

    line_break 10
```

prints: ################