# How to replace a string by using UNIX command?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

How to replace a string by  number of times other/itself string?

e.g. UNIX is good. 
replace UNIX by 4 times
O/p : UNIXUNIXUNIXUNIX is good.

How to do similar way  n times?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiplying strings in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868665/multiplying-strings-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

This one is good too

```
echo 'UNIX is good.' | sed 's/[^ ]*/&&&&/'
```

Comment: If it's for n times? Instead just 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

With this test file:

```
$ cat File
UNIX is good.
```

Try:

```
$ awk -v n=4 '{for (i=1;i<n;i++)sub(/(UNIX)+/, "&UNIX")} 1' File
UNIXUNIXUNIXUNIX is good.
```

Or:

```
$ s='UNIX is good.'
$ n=4; for ((i=1;i<n;i++)); do s=${s/UNIX/UNIXUNIX}; done; echo "$s"
UNIXUNIXUNIXUNIX is good.
```

Answer (score 0):

a perl script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $n= 4;
print 'UNIX'x$n . ' is good';
```