# How do I create a string containing A of an arbitrary length in bash?

Tags: string, bash

How do I create a string of arbitrary length containing A's in bash?

In Ruby or Python, to create a string 5 characters long, I'd do:

```
'A' * 5 #-> 'AAAAA'
```

Comment: Nevermind, I found a related question with alternative keywords:. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868665/multiplying-strings-in-bash-script

Comment: You could try:
`echo "'"|tr -d '\n';for i in {1..5}; do echo A|tr -d '\n'; done; echo "'"|tr -d '\n'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash