# How to add line at perticular line number for blank file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm having following data in file

```
Line 1
```

Now I have to add the three new lines at

```
line number 3,5,6
```

but when I use

```
sed -i '3i string1' file
sed -i '4i string2' file
sed -i '6i string3' file
```

it is not appending the data unless it having some lines in it.

but when that file is empty then it is not add the data as there is no line number which sed can find.

So how I can able to add this line in file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
# insert 5 blank lines into the file
printf "\n%.0s" {1..5} >> file

# now use sed to replace desired line numbers
sed -i '3s/^/string1/; 4s/^/string2/; 6s/^/string3/' file
```

Comment: can use `printf "\n%.0s" {1..5} >> file` also

Comment: Thanks! that `printf` is better than my for loop.

Comment: there's a Q&A on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash :)

Answer (score 0):

To take any `File` and, if needed, add new lines to it as needed to make it at least `n` lines long:

```
awk -i inplace -v n=6 'END{for (i=NR;i<=n;i++) print""} 1' File # GNU awk
```

Or,

```
awk -v n=6 'END{for (i=NR;i<=n;i++) print""} 1' File >tmp && mv tmp File # BSD/OSX awk
```

If the file is already `n` lines long, this does nothing to the file.

After you have done this, your `sed` commands should work.