# Column wise concatenation X no. of time

Tags: unix, echo, paste, concatenation

I have a file with some strings delimited by newline, `in.txt`:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc' > in.txt
$ cat in.txt 
a
b
c
```

And I need to concat a certain fix values to the file for each line in `in.txt` column-wise, so first I did:

```
$ yes '0.0' | head -n 3
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

Then `paste` it:

```
$ yes '0.0' | head -n 3 > 0s
$ paste in.txt 0s 
 a  0.0
 b  0.0
 c  0.0
```

The question is **how do I perform the column wise concatenation X no. of times?** Imagine X is 100,000 , manually typing in `paste in.txt 0s 0s 0s ...` is not feasible.

Comment: Do I understand this right: you want to append a tab and `0.0` to each line of a file, for a specified number of times, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd break the problem into two parts. First, create a tab-separated file of the desired dimensions and content (`R` rows by `C` columns, each cell containing string `F`). Then, paste that generated file onto the existing file:

```
R=$(wc -l < in.txt)   # num rows to generate, in this case same num lines as input
C=100000              # num columns to generate
F=0.0                 # fixed value

paste in.txt <(yes $F | head -$(($R * $C)) | pr -t$C -s$'\t')
```

For the sample input given, with `C=5` columns, I get:

```
a       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
b       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
c       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Breaking that pipeline down, inside out:

- `yes $F` generates a stream of fixed values
- `head -$(($R * $C))` cuts the yes stream off after we've generated all the cells we need
- `pr -t$C -s$'\t'` rotates the stream into a tab-separated table having the number of columns we want
- `<()` puts all the above into an (essentially) temporary file
- `paste in.txt <()` adjoins the two files, row-wise

Comment: Note `wc -l file | cut -f1 -d' '` can be simplified to `wc -l < file`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Sed solutions

You could generate the string you want with `printf` and substitute the end of each line using sed:

```
$ num=5
$ sed 's/$/'"$(for ((i=0; i<num; ++i)); do printf '\t%s' '0.0'; done)"'/' in.txt
a       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
b       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
c       0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

where the value assigned to `num` is the number of columns to be added to your file.

The substitution replaces each line end (`$`) with the output of this command:

```
for (( i=0; i < num; ++i )); do
    printf '\t%s' '0.0'
done
```

If you don't mind using `seq`, this could be simplified to

```
sed 's/$/'"$(printf '\t0.0%.0s' $(seq 1 $num))"'/' in.txt
```

i.e., the command in the substitution is the one-liner

```
printf '\t0.0%.0s' $(seq 1 $num)
```

See for example the question [How can I repeat a character in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash) for many options how to repeat a string in Bash using various tools.

#### Awk solution

This takes `num` as the number of columns to be added and uses a tab as the field separator:

```
awk -v num=5 -v OFS="\t" '{for (i=1; i<=num; ++i) $(NF+1) = "0.0"}1' in.txt
```

The for loop assigns `0.0` to the field one past the last, `num` times; the `1` gets the line printed.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this

```
paste in.txt \`printf '0s %.0s' {1..$X}\`
```

I got that printf part from https://superuser.com/questions/86340/linux-command-to-repeat-a-string-n-times

Answer (score 1):

you can also use for loop as below;

```
paste in.txt $(for i in {1..3}; do echo '0s'; done)
```

or

```
paste in.txt <(for i in {1..X}; do echo $(yes 0.0 | head -3); done)
```

or

```
paste in.txt <(for i in {1..3}; do echo $(yes 1.1 | head -$(wc -l in.txt| awk '{print $1}')); done)
```

Eg:

```
user@host:/tmp$ paste in.txt <(for i in {1..3}; do echo $(yes 1.1 | head -3); done)
a   1.1 1.1 1.1
b   1.1 1.1 1.1
c   1.1 1.1 1.1
```