# Bash expansion. Using variable inside curly braces

Tags: bash, shell, printf, brace-expansion

I want to use the same way of repeating a character as in the [accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/6929294).

But instead of repeating it a predetermined number of times, I want to use a variable. What I tried so far:

```
let a=15
printf "G%.0s" {1..$a}
```

This doesn't work.

What is the correct way to place a variable inside curly braces for expansion?