# Fill a file with a repeated constant value?

Tags: bash, shell, file-io, replicate

I'd like to use standard utilities, rather than compiled code, to efficiently fill a file with a constant value, repeated N times. In the simple version, the  value is a single byte; in a complex version - an arbitrary string.

Note:

- If the value is 0, we have `dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/file bs=XXX count=YYY` for appropriate values of XXX and YYY.
- We can obviously do this with echo `$value >> file` done in a loop, but that should be very slow.

Comment: Does this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/7411306 help?

Comment: Why do you need such a file? It would probably be even *more* efficient to generate such data in the program that needs to read from it.

Comment: @chepner: Suppose I don't control the program.

Comment: Do you want the `yes` program? I'm having trouble imagining what program needs a source of repeated values, other than to autorespond to a series of prompts.

Comment: @chepner: Hmm, that actually does cover some use-cases, see below.

Comment: Rather than opening, appending to, and closing a file at each iteration of your loop with `>>`, you can simply direct the entire output of the loop in one go... `for ((i=0;i<100;i++)) ; do echo "abc"; done > file`

Answer (score 2):

Let's take

```
value_to_replicate="whatever"
file_length=65536
output_file="/path/to/file"
```

for example.

Based on @dmadic's suggestion, we can do:

```
bash -c "printf ${value_to_replicate}%.0s {1..${file_length}} > $output_file"
```

(If I don't "wrap" the final command, there's an issue with the expansion of `${file_length}`). This has a throughput of about 0.6 seconds / MB on my system.

If the string ends with a newline, things become simpler:

```
yes "$value_to_replicate" | head -$file_length > $output_file
```

And if the string has no newlines, we can also do this:

```
yes "$value_to_replicate" | head -$file_length | tr -d '\n' > $output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Perl` as follows:

```
time perl -e 'print "Hello"x1000000000' > /dev/null

real    0m2.930s
user    0m1.778s
sys     0m1.151s
```

So, 5GB in 3 seconds.

Comment: You need to time it when printing into a real file. Also, please mention that a newline is not appended.

Comment: If I time it when printing to a real file, it will be affected by the speed of the disk, whereas I am showing the true sustained bandwidth achieved by the command. If you want linefeeds, just put them in your string! `print "Hello\n"` - you said **arbitrary**, not constrained by having to end in linefeeds.