# Bash: repeat character a variable number of times

Tags: string, bash, repeat

Per the questions and ruminations in:

- [Writing a character N times using the printf command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188658/writing-a-character-n-times-using-the-printf-command)
- [How can I repeat a character in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash)

I would like to learn how one might go about parameterizing the repeat value for a character/string.  For example, the followings works spiffingly:

```
printf "   ,\n%0.s" {1..5}
```

However, if I wanted to parameterize '5', say:

```
num=5
```

I cannot seem to get the expansion correct to make this work.  For instance:

```
printf "   ,\n%0.s" {1..$((num))}
```

fails.

Any thoughts/ideas would be most welcome - I reckon there's a way to do this without having to resort to perl or awk so just curious if poss.

Thanks!

Comment: sequence expression is not possible with variables.

Comment: brace expansions happens before parameter expansion in bash, one have to resort to `eval` or a C style loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can build the command as a string -- with all the parameter expansion you want -- then you can evaluate it. This prints X `num` times:

```
num=10
eval $(echo printf '"X%0.s"' {1..$num})
```

Comment: Kicking myself for forgetting eval.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `seq`

```
num=20;
printf '\n%.0s' $(seq $num)
```

Comment: If one resorts to an external command then AWK would be more portable, as `seq` is part of GNU coreutils.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  Per the other comment, I'd like to stick to something as portable as possible, hence my selection of the eval solution but I appreciate this suggestion and its workaround to the dangers of using eval.

Answer (score 1):

A slighly different approach

```
$ repeat() {
    local str=$1 n=$2 spaces
    printf -v spaces "%*s" $n " "     # create a string of spaces $n chars long
    printf "%s" "${spaces// /$str}"   # substitute each space with the requested string
}
$ repeat '!' 10
!!!!!!!!!!                     # <= no newline
$ repeat $'   ,\n' 5
   ,
   ,
   ,
   ,
   ,
```