# Bash print repeated dash char is not working for my with printf

Tags: linux, bash

I have been trying to implement printing a line made up of dashes. The most efficient/simple looking answer I found is: [top-answer-from-here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash)

Where to print 100 equals you do:

`printf '=%.0s' {1..100}`

to print 100 underscores you do:

`printf '_%.0s' {1..100}`

But to print 100 dashes I get an error: invalid option

`printf '-%.0s' {1..100}`

I have tried to escape the - but then I get 100 "-"':

`\-\-\-\-\-\-...etc...`

How can I solve this?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22764/dashes-in-printf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate arguments using `--`:

```
printf -- '-%.0s' {1..100}
```

Comment: Sweet : ) ..thanks very much.. just got to wait 8 mins until I can accept as the answer