# simplify repeating input to printf bash

Tags: bash, shell

Instead of multiple `${DOWN}`'s is it possible to repeat x number of times?

```
readonly RED='\033[0;31m'
readonly NC='\033[0m' # No Color
readonly DOWN='\xE2\x96\xBC'
printf "%b%b%b%b look down %b%b%b%b\n" "${RED}" "${DOWN}" "${DOWN}" "${DOWN}" "${DOWN}" "${DOWN}" "${DOWN}" "${NC}"

▼▼▼ look down ▼▼▼
```

Comment: Did you have a look here? <https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/8133920>

Comment: You probably don't have to hard-code UTF-8 sequences: `readonly DOWN=$'\u25bc'`.

Comment: `RED=$(tput setaf 1); NC=$(tput setaf 9); DOWN=$(tput cud 1)`.  And, to make your life really easy: `DOWN5=$(tput cud 5)`

Comment: @WilliamPursell `DOWN` is an arrow character, not a cursor movement command.

Answer (score 0):

Use some command to repeat your down-string.

```
printf "%b%b%b%b look down %b%b%b%b\n" "${RED}" $(yes "${DOWN}" | head -6) "${NC}"
# or
printf "%b%b%b%b look down %b%b%b%b\n" "${RED}" $(for ((i=0;i<6;i++)); do echo "${DOWN}"; done) "${NC}"
# or
printf "%b%b%b%b look down %b%b%b%b\n" "${RED}" $(echo {1..6} | sed "s/[^ ]*/${DOWN}/g") "${NC}"
```

With above solutions you need to count the number of `%b` you use.
Perhaps you want something like

```
msg=" look down "
count=10
for ((i=0;i<${count};i++)); do
    msg="${DOWN}${msg}${DOWN}"
done
printf "%b%b%b\n" "${RED}" "${msg}" "${NC}"
```

Not `printf "%b$msg%b\n" "${RED}" "${NC}"`, this goes wrong when msg has a `%`.