# bash equivalent of string multiplication in python ("=" * { n })

Tags: python, string, bash

Is there a **bash equivalent** to python's elegant **string multiplication**?

```
>>> "=" * 8
'========'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repeat a character in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use printf.

`printf '=%.0s' {1..8}`

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
myString=$(printf "%10s");echo ${myString// /=}
```

Comment: this element to adjust - "%10s"    ---    "%8s"