# How to add 10 spaces at the frontend | Unix |

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a text file : `ABC.txt` which contain below data

```
A Apple a day keeps a doctor away 
B I like to play with Ball
C I have cat at my home
D My Dog name is bob
```

I want to display output on my screen with 10 spaces in a frontend and then my file data

**Expected output :**

```
      A Apple a day keeps a doctor away 
      B I like to play with Ball
      C I have cat at my home
      D My Dog name is bob
```

**I have tried this but not working**

**Command :**

```
cat ABC.txt  | column -t
```

Comment: `sed 's/^/          /' ABC.txt`

Comment: @Barmar : Is their any way if i give 10 then 10 spaces will be addded ... incase if i want to set it to 25 spaces then

Comment: I've updated the answer to use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
prefix='          '
sed "s/^/$prefix/" ABC.txt
```

`^` matches the beginning of the line, and this replaces it with 10 spaces.

If the number of spaces can vary, you can calculate the `prefix` variable instead of hard-coding it. See [How can I repeat a character in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash)