# Repeating - character to terminal

Tags: bash

I want to print a sequence of `-` characters.

Have done

```
printf '=%.0s' {1..55}
```

But get no printing with

```
printf '-%.0s' {1..55}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to insert a newline at the end?

Comment: on my system the 2nd `printf` generates a syntax error; if this happens on your system then consider updating the question to show the complete output when running the 2nd `printf`

Comment: See [How can I repeat a character in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5349718/4154375) for other ways to repeat a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` accepts arguments. `'-%s'` is recognized as an option, which is an invalid one.

You can use `--` to mark the end of command options:

```bash
printf -- '-%.0s' {1..55}
```

Comment: Can one add a newline at the end?

Comment: You could also put the `-` to the end of the formatting string instead of having to use `--`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method:

```
printf -v blanks '%55s' ''
echo ${blanks// /-}
```