# bash: printf ("%.s ") doesn't keep whitespaces after the s

Tags: bash, printf, whitespace

I have a piece of code like this:

```
printf "%.s  "  $(seq 1 $count)
```

It actually belongs to an else condition and its job is to print out
whitespaces $count times..

It works fine if I enter a string like this:

```
printf "%.shelloworld  "  $(seq 1 $count)
```

but not when i just put in whitespaces.

Any work arounds?

Comment: Your code prints whitespaces for me. Are you sure it doesn't work for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print a character repeatedly in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799303/print-a-character-repeatedly-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
# printf "%.s  "  $(seq 1 10) | hexdump -C
00000000  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
00000010  20 20 20 20                                       |    |
```

Is this the *exact* command that's being entered, or is there other variable substitution happening? Because the exact thing you seem to be experiencing would happen if you didn't quote a particular variable expansion:

```
# frm="%.s  "; printf $frm $(seq 1 10) | hexdump -C
[no output]
```

Whereas:

```
# frm="%.s  "; printf "$frm" $(seq 1 10) | hexdump -C
00000000  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
00000010  20 20 20 20                                       |    |
```

Comment: At the moment, I have: if [ bla bla ];then printf bla elif [bla];then printf "<spaces here dont stay>|--"

Comment: @KevinMcInerney: Do you have a line that, when pasted into a fresh terminal, shows the problem?

Comment: @KevinMcInerney you can run your script via `bash -x` and it will show you exactly how the shell is interpreting your script as it runs.