# Repeating a character using printf and outputting to variable

Tags: string, bash, printf

I'm having trouble making a string out of repeated single characters.
This works when I'm not assigning it to a variable:

```
printf "*%.0s" $(seq 1 $(expr $1 / 2))
```

This just assigns the script name to `test`:

```
printf -v test "*%.0s" $(seq 1 $(expr $1 / 2))
```

I also tried:

```
test=$(printf "*%.0s" $(seq 1 $(expr $1 / 2)))
```

But it does the same thing.

Why doesn't this work, and is there another way to build a string and assign it to a variable?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I'm expecting `test` to contain $1 / 2 asterisks. (i.e. "****" if $1 / 2 results in 4)

Comment: You question has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799303/print-a-character-repeatedly-in-bash) .

Comment: I tried that as well, but my variable still just contained my script name. I tried `test=$(echo "${testprep// /*}")`

Comment: What's the problem with `printf -v test "*%.0s" $(seq 1 $(expr $1 / 2))` code? It works fine for me.

Comment: When I do `echo $test` it spits out test.sh (which is my script name)

Comment: That's a pretty cool method. I usually do `printf "%*s" $(($1/2)) " " | tr " " "*"` -- create a string of spaces of the required length, then translate the spaces to your desired character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `test` is fine; you just need to quote its expansion:

```
echo "$test"
```

Otherwise, the asterisks in the value are expanded to the contents of the current directory via pathname expansion.

Comment: What if we have more than one asterisk? Shouldn't all of them be expanded ?

Comment: As a single pattern, each additional asterisk is redundant. How it is explicitly interpreted is a matter of implementation, but conceptually each asterisk matches some substring of the final result. For example, `***` could match `foo` with each asterisk matching a single letter, or the first asterisk matching `foo` and the others matching empty strings, etc.

Comment: Good to know. Thank You

Comment: `val=$(expr $1 / 2);s=$(printf "%-${val}s" "$2");test=$(echo "${s// /$2}");
echo "${test}";` I prepared this general solution for OPs problem. But not sure it it will work for all the inputs though. Works like `./somescript 30 *` or `./somescript 30 \\ `

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would come down to something very simple. The general solution might come in handy as well.

Comment: @baiumbg : Please test it thoroughly though and remember to escape the escape sequences ;)

Comment: Also, don't use `expr`; `val=$(( $1 / 2 ))`