# Draw a horizontal line from dash character occupying the full width of a terminal in bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I need a command that will draw a horizontal "line" in the terminal. The line must be exactly the width of the terminal long (regardless of a current terminal width) and consist of a dash character (although a unicode symbol for a horizontal line can be also used).

It is better if it can be colored.

I need to use it like this:

```
echo some text
drawline
echo more text
```

And the output would look something like this:

```
echo some text
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo more text
```

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/snipplets/print_horizontal_line#a_line_across_the_entire_width_of_the_terminal

Comment: for zsh: https://superuser.com/questions/845744/how-to-draw-a-line-between-commands-in-zsh-shell

Answer (score 34):

Try with:

```
echo some text
printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -
echo some text
```

Comment: No [attribution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/snipplets/print_horizontal_line#a_line_across_the_entire_width_of_the_terminal)?

Comment: Could someone please explain how this works? I'd like to be able to make it shorter by n characters.

Answer (score 22):

In bash and zsh there is the `$COLUMNS` variable which you can use.

I use this line for that purpose:

```
printf %"$COLUMNS"s |tr " " "-"
```

You can also use `seq`, but this is not as intuitive as the other solution:

```
seq -s- $COLUMNS|tr -d '[:digit:]'
```

**Edit:**

It seems that `$COLUMNS` is a local bash variable and you will need to export it. So now there are (at least) 2 options.

1. Export the variable before you call the script:

   ```
   export COLUMNS; ./your_script.sh
   ```
2. Use `tput` as Zumo de Vidrio suggests.

   ```
   printf %"$(tput cols)"s |tr " " "-"
   ```

Comment: The thing is that it works on command line but not in the script.

Comment: Ok, it seems that I exported the `COLUMNS`, that's why it works. You can either do the same or use a combination of @Zumo de Vidrio and my solution. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 18):

I'll add some details to the [current top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42762743/1720199). You can use the following ["hack"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030976/1720199) (also as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/1720199)):

```sh
printf '%.s─' $(seq 1 $(tput cols))
```

Notice how this doesn't use the simple dash `-` but instead the [box drawing](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Box_Drawing_(Unicode_block)) dash `─`. This way consecutive dashes actually connects which prints a nice continuous line:

```sh
This nice line   ────────────────────────────
And not this one ----------------------------
```

You can for example use this to show a line before (and/or after) every command registering [hooks using zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions)

```
# ~/.zshrc
draw_hline=false
preexec() {
  if [[ $1 == ls* ]]; then
    hline
    draw_hline=true
  fi
}

precmd() {
  if [ $draw_hline = true ]; then
    hline
    echo
  fi
  draw_hline=false
}
```

Registering hooks using bash can probably be done in a very similar way using [this](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec#bash-preexec).

Comment: In Bash, brace expansion happens first (before command substitution), so you'd get just a single -. To see why, do ```set -x; echo {1..$(tput cols)}; set +x``` and you'll see the echo command as ```+ echo '{1..80}'``` not the numbers 1 thru 80. You can change the evaluation order by doing  ```eval printf '%.s-' \{1..$(tput cols)}``` and you'd have to move the - to after the %.s to avoid printf thinking it is an option leader. But, you could get what you want more simply by doing ```printf '%.s-' $(seq 1 $(tput cols))``` without using brace expansion at all.

Comment: Strange both `set -x; echo $(seq 1 $(tput cols)); set +x` and `set -x; echo {1..$(tput cols)}; set +x` produce the exact same output on my machine. Both output `echo 1 2 3 … 120 \n 1 2 3 … 120`. Maybe zsh function a different way, I'll update to have a more stable version across shells. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**A simple Perl one-liner**
`stty size | perl -ale 'print "-"x$F[1]'`

---

**NOTE**
you can see the **height** and **width** of your terminal with `stty size`

---

[image]

Comment: great. to clarify: it prints `-` `$F[1]` amount of times. `$F[1]` being the second value (separated by whitespace) of `stty size` command output, eg. `57 228`. i think `print('string'x$number)` is an awesome [tag:perl] construct.

Comment: @w17t thank you for your feedback. I am not sure to understand you well. It might you want to use it this way: `perl -le 'print "-" x qx(stty size | grep -o ...\$)'` without `-a` for separators and `@F` array.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `tput` to set colors and `printf` to print line according to number of columns.

```
export RED=$(tput setaf 1 :-"" 2>/dev/null)
export GREEN=$(tput setaf 2 :-"" 2>/dev/null)
export YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3 :-"" 2>/dev/null)
export BLUE=$(tput setaf 4 :-"" 2>/dev/null)
export RESET=$(tput sgr0 :-"" 2>/dev/null)

echo $GREEN some text $RESET
echo $RED; printf -- "-%.0s" $(seq $(tput cols)); echo $RESET
echo $YELLOW more text $RESET
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Super simple horizontal ruler:

`repeat $(tput cols) echo -ne "-";`