# How to draw a horizontal line across a terminal in zsh?

Tags: terminal, zsh

The aim is to to draw a line across a terminal using only zsh builtins.

---

*Note that [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762643/draw-a-horizontal-line-from-dash-character-occupying-the-full-width-of-a-termina) has been asked already about bash. This one is specific to zsh.*

Answer (score 2):

**This code**

`print -- ${(l:COLUMNS::─:)}`

**Prints this line**

──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

*Note*: The character (─) is [a box drawing character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Similar_Unicode_characters), not a hyphen. Also, `COLUMNS` is a zsh parameter whose value is the width of the terminal. You could replace that with a specific width, e.g., 80.

Comment: How does the form `${(....)}`, i.e. without a parameter name, work in general? An explanation would be helpful. BTW, I suggest in this case to use `${(l:COLUMNS::─:):-}` instead. This would then even work, if you have activated `set -u` in your shell.

Comment: Explanation is a pragmatic affair. I doubt more granularity would be so helpful here. If I explain the `l` flag, then why not explain the others? There comes a point when we should consult further reference materials in order to learn more. My feeling is that the concision here is warranted.