# Shell - How to add incremental blank space per line

Tags: shell, unix

```
if [ $(grep -c 'Health Status: RED' $LOG) -gt 0 ]; then
    $(grep 'Server:' $LOG > $TMP )
    while read -r line
    do
        echo "$instance,1,$line"
    done < "$TMP"

    else
    echo "\n$instance,0,Health Status: GREEN\n"
fi
```

The output of above code is as follows:

```
Instance1,1,Server: EMEA

Instance1,1,Server: NAM

Instance1,1,Server: ASIA

Instance1,1,Server: AUSTRALIA
```

I need to add incremental space in `$instance` variable per line, add one space after `$instance` like below. Please note number of lines are not fixed.

```
Instance1 ,1,Server: EMEA  ==> One blank space added after Instance1

Instance1  ,1,Server: NAM ==> two blank spaces added after Instance1

Instance1   ,1,Server: ASIA ==> three blank spaces added after Instance1

Instance1    ,1,Server: AUSTRALIA ==> four blank spaces added after Instance1
```

any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you feed your snippet to https://www.shellcheck.net, it'll tell you a lot of useful things. I can see these: `[ $(grep -c ...) -gt 0 ]` instead of `grep -q ...`; multiple unquoted command substitutions; command substitution where it doesn't make sense; lots of unquoted variables; `echo` with escape characters in the string; useless temporary file instead of process substitution.

Comment: Thansk for looking into it, I agree to what you are saying I being novice coder and will try to refine the code later, for now its giving me the desired output, just need some inputs on how can I add blank spaces.

Comment: What is `$(grep 'Server:' $LOG > $TMP )` for?  You are executing grep, writing output to a file, then taking the null string and trying to execute it.  Remove the `$()` around the grep.

Comment: Instead of `if [ $(grep -c 'Health Status: RED' $LOG) -gt 0 ]`, just write `if grep -q 'Health Status: Red' "$LOG"; then ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `while`, with this:

```
spaces_counter=1
while read -r line
do
    echo "$instance$(printf "%0.s " $(seq 1 $spaces_counter)),1,$line"
    (( spaces_counter += 1 ))
done < "$TMP"
```

Some explanations:

- `$(seq 1 $spaces_counter)`: outputs the integers from 1 to `$spaces_counter`
- `$(printf "%0.s " $(seq 1 $spaces_counter))`: uses the seq from above to print a certain number of spaces.
- the character after "%0.s " is where you specify the character you want repeated.

This is based on this answer: [Print a character repeatedly in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799303/print-a-character-repeatedly-in-bash)

combined with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use printf like below

```
for ((i=3;i<10;i++)); do
   printf "%*s\n" $i ",1,"
done
```