# Fill argv[1] in C with max input

Tags: c, argv

I am trying figure out a simple way to fill `argv[1]` with an extremely large string of input to see how much input my program can handle. Any ideas on the simplest way to do this?

Comment: This seems pointless, but you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349718/how-can-i-repeat-a-character-in-bash) for suggetions on how to piece together a large value to pass to the program in the shell.

Comment: `argv[1]`, in case you are designating the second parameter to the `main()` function, is operating system dependant.  You have not specified neither the operating system, nor any sample code to be able to decide how to answer you.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling your program from a shell, you typically take the advantage of that.

For instance, for POSIX, something like:

```
./program `printf '%*s' 500 | tr ' ' x`
```

<sup>(Taken from [Creating string of repeated characters in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211891/creating-string-of-repeated-characters-in-shell-script))</sup>

You can also create the string dynamically over a loop to test the program until it crashes, etc.

---

If you want a C solution (without spawning another process, e.g. using something like `system` or OS-specific APIs), I would suggest you rename your `main()` into a different function, and then write a new `main()` that calls the old one with an `argv` customized however you like:

```
int old_main(int argc, char *argv[]) { ... }

int main()
{
    int argc = 2;
    char *argv[2] = {
        "program",
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    };
    return old_main(argc, argv);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a POSIX shell (Like Bash on Linux or similar) then you could use a simply Python script to "fill" an argument, and call it using the shell back-tick to execute commands "inline":

```
./your_program `python -c "print('A'*100)"`
```

The above will create a string of 100 `A` characters as the first argument to the program.