# Generate all permutations of up to `n` letters

Tags: bash, shell, permutation, brace-expansion

I'd like to generate all permutations of letters up to length `n`

For example, for the argument `2` I'd like obtain a list like

```
a
aa
..
az
...
z
za
..
zz
```

---

I tried using a for loop to generate `n` increasingly larger brace expansions by repeating `{a..z}` [^1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23087599/2607891) and appending it to a variable. But this doesn't seem to work.

```bash
OUT=""

# loop from 1 to first argument
for ((i=1; i<=$1; i++))
do
    OUT+=$(echo $(printf '{a..z}%.0s' {1..$i}))
done

OUT=$(echo $OUT | sort)

echo $OUT
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chained brace expansions don't scale well. You're better off with a function like this:

```
# Usage: perms n [prefix]
perms() {
  if (($1 < 1)); then
    return
  fi

  for pfix in "$2"{a..z}; do
    printf '%s\n' "$pfix"
    perms $(($1 - 1)) "$pfix"
  done
}
```

```
$ perms 2
a
aa
ab
ac
...
```

But if you insist on it, this is how you should do it:

```
# Usage: perms n
perms() {
  printf -v brace_exp '{a..z}%*s' $(($1 - 1))
  brace_exp=${brace_exp// /'{,{a..z}}'}
  eval "printf '%s\n' $brace_exp"
}
```

Comment: Very clean, and being already sorted is a nice bonus!

Comment: Is there also a clever way to generate all permutations of exactly `n` letters (discarding the shorter ones)?

Comment: @mdcq Move printf above return https://ideone.com/eZb34s

Answer (score 6):

This is a case where `eval` might be your best bet. There isn't a security concern as long as you strictly control the content of `brace_string` and it allows you to build a list of brace expansions that can do what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

make_list() {
  brace_string=""
  for ((i=0 ; i < $1 ; i++)) ; do
    brace_string+="{a..z}"
    eval printf "'%s\n'" "${brace_string}"
  done
}

make_list "$1" | sort
```

The problem with `{1..$i}` or with building a list of brace expansions in a variable without `eval` is that the bash parser evaluates syntax before it expands variables.  That means `{1..$i}` is just treated like a string because `$i` isn't a single character or integer (it gets *replaced* by an integer later, but bash can't see into the future). `eval` works around this by letting you perform all the parsing steps twice, meaning `$i` can get replaced on the first parsing and then the brace expansion is valid on the second parsing. And, more relevant to the above example, `"$brace_string"` won't be treated as a brace expansion on the first parsing because the variable hasn't been replaced by the time bash does syntax analysis, but it can be handled on a second parsing through `eval`.

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Though it seems to buffer all data in memory before it's outputted, e.g. using `foo.sh > out.txt`. Is it possible to make this "streaming" such that it doesn't buffer all data in memory?

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

n=$1
(( n == 0 )) && exit 0
perms=( {z..a} )
while (( (ilast = ${#perms[*]}-1) >= 0 )); do
    p=${perms[ilast]}
    unset 'perms[ilast]'

    printf '%s\n' "$p"
    (( ${#p} < n )) && perms+=( "$p"{z..a} )
done
```

- The code uses an array as a stack to implement an iterative [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) of a tree of permutations.
- It's been tested with Bash versions 3, 4, and 5.

The code can be made significantly faster (around 4x) by outputting the maximum-length permutations in alphabet-sized groups:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

n=$1
(( n == 0 )) && exit 0
perms=( {z..a} )
while (( (ilast = ${#perms[*]}-1) >= 0 )); do
    p=${perms[ilast]}
    unset 'perms[ilast]'

    printf '%s\n' "$p"
    if (( ${#p} < (n-1) )); then
        perms+=( "$p"{z..a} )
    elif (( ${#p} == (n-1) )); then
        printf '%s\n' "$p"{a..z}
    fi
done
```

- On my (unexotic) test VM, this code generated all permutations up to length 4 in 3s, 5 in 1.5m, and 6 in 41m.