# Using Bash to display a progress indicator (spinner)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, progress

Using a bash only script, how can you provide a bash progress indicator?

For example, when I run a command from bash - while that command is executing - let the user know that something is still happening.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script which concentrates more on the drawing part.

Comment: [Pipe Viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) can be injected into a pipeline to generate a status bar, spinner, &c. automatically.

Comment: Check out [`eta`](https://github.com/aioobe/eta)!

Answer (score 100, accepted):

In this example using SCP, I'm demonstrating how to grab the process id (pid) and then do something while that process is running.

This displays a simple spinnng icon.

```
/usr/bin/scp me@website.com:file somewhere 2>/dev/null &
pid=$! # Process Id of the previous running command

spin[0]="-"
spin[1]="\\"
spin[2]="|"
spin[3]="/"

echo -n "[copying] ${spin[0]}"
while [ kill -0 $pid ]
do
  for i in "${spin[@]}"
  do
        echo -ne "\b$i"
        sleep 0.1
  done
done
```

---

William Pursell's solution

```
/usr/bin/scp me@website.com:file somewhere 2>/dev/null &
pid=$! # Process Id of the previous running command

spin='-\|/'

i=0
while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null
do
  i=$(( (i+1) %4 ))
  printf "\r${spin:$i:1}"
  sleep .1
done
```

Comment: +1 This is really good: A third of the LOC other solutions use.

Comment: You need to run `scp` in the background, or it completes before the rest of this script runs. (Backgrounding is also required for `$!` to have any meaning).

Comment: It's much simpler to do: `s='-\|/'; i=0; while kill -0 $pid; do i=$(( (i+1) %4 )); printf "\r${s:$i:1}"; sleep .1; done`

Comment: @chepner Good point, I just missed off the `&`.
@WilliamPursell Yes, though not sure how clear that is!

Comment: However, this doesn't really indicate progress. It's just a flashy way of showing that `$pid` hasn't completed yet, which is readily observed by keeping the process in the foreground in the first place.

Comment: I did something similar in `Python`, which I had to fire up another `thread` to print the progress while at the same time keep the task going, never thought could just put the `process` in background and `wait` in `bash`. :)

Comment: Very nice and it works. But is there a way to also get the exit code of the finished job after the spinner is done?

Comment: The spinner interferes with variable assignment, e.g. foo=$(callALongFunction) 2>/dev/null & (spinner code) will prevent callALongFunction from assigning any value to foo. Removing the spinner fixes this. Any ideas how to avoid this issue?

Comment: @DavidD You can write to stderr if you are not capturing that or modify the logic to use something like `exec 3>$(tty);` `echo -en "$1" | tee >(cat - >&3);` `exec 3>&-;` This will allow you to clone standard out on fd 3 so you can see whats printed on the screen and still capture the output in a variable within another script.

Comment: `while [ kill -0 $pid ]` causes `line 102: [: -0: binary operator expected` error for me. I have to use `while kill -0 $pid;` instead!

Comment: Can we use that without showing the command at the end of the loop?

Answer (score 31):

If you have a way to estimate percentage done, such as the current number of files processed and total number, you can make a simple linear progress meter with a little math and assumptions about screen width.

```
count=0
total=34
pstr="[=======================================================================]"

while [ $count -lt $total ]; do
  sleep 0.5 # this is work
  count=$(( $count + 1 ))
  pd=$(( $count * 73 / $total ))
  printf "\r%3d.%1d%% %.${pd}s" $(( $count * 100 / $total )) $(( ($count * 1000 / $total) % 10 )) $pstr
done
```

Or instead of a linear meter you could estimate time remaining.  It's about as accurate as other similar things.

```
count=0
total=34
start=`date +%s`

while [ $count -lt $total ]; do
  sleep 0.5 # this is work
  cur=`date +%s`
  count=$(( $count + 1 ))
  pd=$(( $count * 73 / $total ))
  runtime=$(( $cur-$start ))
  estremain=$(( ($runtime * $total / $count)-$runtime ))
  printf "\r%d.%d%% complete ($count of $total) - est %d:%0.2d remaining\e[K" $(( $count*100/$total )) $(( ($count*1000/$total)%10)) $(( $estremain/60 )) $(( $estremain%60 ))
done
printf "\ndone\n"
```

Comment: How can I estimate the files that are still to copy? You mean take a count of the current files at the start and then every loop count how many are on the remote system? (genuinely interested rather than saying you're wrong)

Comment: It depends completely on your task.  For instance, if you're using scp to copy a bunch of files, you could call it separately for each file rather than using `*`.  Or as you suggest you could check on the remote system for the number of files or file sizes, although that could be fairly expensive to do.

Comment: @evil otto. Thank you very much. Kindly where in the previous code we should call the command that we need to watch it is progress?

Comment: @goro - in my example the command that is doing work is "sleep 0.5", so that would be your `scp` command.

Answer (score 27):

Referred from [here](http://fitnr.com/showing-a-bash-spinner.html) is a nice spinner function (with slight modification), will help your cursor to stay in original position also.

```
spinner()
{
    local pid=$!
    local delay=0.75
    local spinstr='|/-\'
    while [ "$(ps a | awk '{print $1}' | grep $pid)" ]; do
        local temp=${spinstr#?}
        printf " [%c]  " "$spinstr"
        local spinstr=$temp${spinstr%"$temp"}
        sleep $delay
        printf "\b\b\b\b\b\b"
    done
    printf "    \b\b\b\b"
}
```

with usage:

```
(a_long_running_task) &
spinner
```

Comment: How would one be able to add a custom message after the "spinner"?

Comment: @xcy7e웃 : I extended this in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50699733/1184842

Comment: @xcy7e what if you want to get a string output from the `a_long_running_task`, how would you handle that use-case?

Comment: @qodeninja I recommend you open a new thread with your question as this one has been closed.

Comment: @xcy7e yeah no. I'm already traumatized with adding questions to this site. and this slight clarifitation doesnt warrant a new question.

Comment: @qodeninja yes it does.

Answer (score 24):

**This is a pretty easy technique:**
(just replace `sleep 20` with whatever command you want to indicate is running)

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 20 & PID=$! #simulate a long process

echo "THIS MAY TAKE A WHILE, PLEASE BE PATIENT WHILE ______ IS RUNNING..."
printf "["
# While process is running...
while kill -0 $PID 2> /dev/null; do 
    printf  "▓"
    sleep 1
done
printf "] done!"
```

**The output looks like this:**

```
> THIS MAY TAKE A WHILE, PLEASE BE PATIENT WHILE ______ IS RUNNING...
> [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓] done!
```

It adds a `▓` (high density dotted) every second until the process is complete.

Comment: how do you use this within a function?

Comment: You could start the process, get the PID, then pass it into a function that contains the  code between the `echo` and the `done!`

Comment: Hi guys works good and smooth! would you tell me what kill -0 means?

Answer (score 16):

Here a simple one-liner, that I use:

```
while true; do for X in '-' '/' '|' '\'; do echo -en "\b$X"; sleep 0.1; done; done
```

Comment: Example usage:   echo doing something that takes ten seconds...; sleep 10 & while [ "$(ps a | awk '{print $1}' | grep $!)" ] ; do for X in '-' '/' '|' '\'; do echo -en "\b$X"; sleep 0.1; done; done

Comment: This rotatis in endless loop

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example of an 'activity indicator,' for an internet connection speed test via the linux 'speedtest-cli' command:

```
## BASH shell
printf '\n\tInternet speed test:  '

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498304/using-bash-to-display-a-progress-working-indicator

spin[0]="-"
spin[1]="\\"
spin[2]="|"
spin[3]="/"

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165057/executing-bash-loop-while-command-is-running

speedtest > .st.txt &           ## & : continue running script
pid=$!                          ## PID of last command

# If this script is killed, kill 'speedtest':
trap "kill $pid 2> /dev/null" EXIT

# While 'speedtest' is running:
while kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null; do
for i in "${spin[@]}"
do
    echo -ne "\b$i"
    sleep 0.1
done
done

# Disable the trap on a normal exit:
trap - EXIT

printf "\n\t           "
grep Download: .st.txt
printf "\t             "
grep Upload: .st.txt
echo ''
rm -f st.txt
```

**Update - example:**

[image: animated GIF]

Comment: Internet speed test:  zsh: spin: assignment to invalid subscript range

Comment: @alper this is for bash, not zsh

Answer (score 6):

Here's my attempt. I'm new to bash scripts so some of this code may be terrible :)

Example Output:

[image: In Progress]
[image: Done]

The Code:

```
progressBarWidth=20

# Function to draw progress bar
progressBar () {

  # Calculate number of fill/empty slots in the bar
  progress=$(echo "$progressBarWidth/$taskCount*$tasksDone" | bc -l)  
  fill=$(printf "%.0f\n" $progress)
  if [ $fill -gt $progressBarWidth ]; then
    fill=$progressBarWidth
  fi
  empty=$(($fill-$progressBarWidth))

  # Percentage Calculation
  percent=$(echo "100/$taskCount*$tasksDone" | bc -l)
  percent=$(printf "%0.2f\n" $percent)
  if [ $(echo "$percent>100" | bc) -gt 0 ]; then
    percent="100.00"
  fi

  # Output to screen
  printf "\r["
  printf "%${fill}s" '' | tr ' ' ▉
  printf "%${empty}s" '' | tr ' ' ░
  printf "] $percent%% - $text "
}



## Collect task count
taskCount=33
tasksDone=0

while [ $tasksDone -le $taskCount ]; do

  # Do your task
  (( tasksDone += 1 ))

  # Add some friendly output
  text=$(echo "somefile-$tasksDone.dat")

  # Draw the progress bar
  progressBar $taskCount $taskDone $text

  sleep 0.01
done

echo
```

You can see the source here:
https://gist.github.com/F1LT3R/fa7f102b08a514f2c535

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the classical spinner, you can use [this progress bar](https://web.archive.org/web/20190203164249/https://ownyourbits.com/2017/07/16/a-progress-bar-for-the-shell/)

It achieves subcharacter precision by using [half block characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements#Character_table)

[image]

Code included on the link.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/extensionsapp/progre.sh

Create 82 percent progress: `progreSh 82`

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to shift this entire thing with tab ?

Comment: How can I add it to Oh My ZSH when booting?

Answer (score 1):

I extended the answer of [checksum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407685/checksum) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20369590/1184842) by displaying a variable info message after the spinner:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
function spinner() {
    local info="$1"
    local pid=$!
    local delay=0.75
    local spinstr='|/-\'
    while kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null; do
        local temp=${spinstr#?}
        printf " [%c]  $info" "$spinstr"
        local spinstr=$temp${spinstr%"$temp"}
        sleep $delay
        local reset="\b\b\b\b\b\b"
        for ((i=1; i<=$(echo $info | wc -c); i++)); do
            reset+="\b"
        done
        printf $reset
    done
    printf "    \b\b\b\b"
}

# usage:
(a_long_running_task) &
spinner "performing long running task..."
```

I don't like that if the stdout output with a spinner is redirected to a file, `less` shows `^H` for each backspace instead of avoiding them in a file output at all. Is that possible with an easy spinner like this one?

Answer (score 0):

@DavidD's comments on Pez Cuckows answer, this is an example of how you can capture the output of the progress bar in a script and still see the spinner on the screen:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

#############################################################################
###########################################################################
###
### Modified/Rewritten by A.M.Danischewski (c) 2015 v1.1
### Issues: If you find any issues emai1 me at my <first name> dot 
###         <my last name> at gmail dot com.  
###
### Based on scripts posted by Pez Cuckow, William Pursell at:  
### http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498304/using-bash-to-display-\
###      a-progress-working-indicator
###
### This program runs a program passed in and outputs a timing of the 
### command and it exec's a new fd for stdout so you can assign a 
### variable the output of what was being run. 
### 
### This is a very new rough draft but could be expanded. 
### 
### This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
### it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
### the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
### (at your option) any later version.
###
### This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
### but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
### MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
### GNU General Public License for more details.
###
### You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
### along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
###########################################################################
#############################################################################

declare    CMD="${1}"
shift      ## Clip the first value of the $@, the rest are the options. 
declare    CMD_OPTIONS="$@"
declare    CMD_OUTPUT=""
declare    TMP_OUTPUT="/tmp/_${0##*/}_$$_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N)" 
declare -r SPIN_DELAY="0.1"
declare -i PID=

function usage() {
cat <<EOF

Description: ${0##*/}

This program runs a program passed in and outputs a timing of the 
command and it exec's a new fd for stdout so you can assign a variable 
the output of what was being run. 

Usage: ${0##*/} <command> [command options]

 E.g.  
    >$ ${0##*/} sleep 5 \&\& echo "hello" \| figlet
     Running: sleep 5 && echo hello | figlet, PID 2587:/

     real   0m5.003s
     user   0m0.000s
     sys    0m0.002s
      _          _ _       
     | |__   ___| | | ___  
     | '_ \ / _ \ | |/ _ \ 
     | | | |  __/ | | (_) |
     |_| |_|\___|_|_|\___/ 

     Done..
    >$ var=\$(${0##*/} sleep 5 \&\& echo hi)
     Running: sleep 5 && echo hi, PID 32229:-
     real   0m5.003s
     user   0m0.000s
     sys    0m0.001s
     Done..
     >$ echo \$var
     hi

EOF
} 

function spin_wait() { 
 local -a spin 
 spin[0]="-"
 spin[1]="\\"
 spin[2]="|"
 spin[3]="/"
 echo -en "Running: ${CMD} ${CMD_OPTIONS}, PID ${PID}: " >&3
 while kill -0 ${PID} 2>/dev/random; do
   for i in "${spin[@]}"; do
     echo -ne "\b$i" >&3
     sleep ${SPIN_DELAY}
   done
 done
} 

function run_cmd() { 
 exec 3>$(tty)
 eval "time ${CMD} ${CMD_OPTIONS}" 2>>"${TMP_OUTPUT}" | tee "${TMP_OUTPUT}" & 
 PID=$! # Set global PID to process id of the command we just ran. 
 spin_wait
 echo -en "\n$(< "${TMP_OUTPUT}")\n" >&3 
 echo -en "Done..\n" >&3
 rm "${TMP_OUTPUT}"
 exec 3>&-
} 

if [[ -z "${CMD}" || "${CMD}" =~ ^-. ]]; then 
 usage | more && exit 0 
else 
 run_cmd  
fi 

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Psychedelic progress bar for bash scripting. Call by command line as './progressbar x y'  where 'x' is a time in seconds and 'y' is a message to display. The inner function progressbar() works standalone as well and takes 'x' as a percentage and 'y' as a message.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then echo "x is \"time in seconds\" and z is \"message\""; echo "Usage: progressbar x z"; exit; fi
progressbar() {
        local loca=$1; local loca2=$2;
        declare -a bgcolors; declare -a fgcolors;
        for i in {40..46} {100..106}; do
                bgcolors+=("$i")
        done
        for i in {30..36} {90..96}; do
                fgcolors+=("$i")
        done
        local u=$(( 50 - loca ));
        local y; local t;
        local z; z=$(printf '%*s' "$u");
        local w=$(( loca * 2 ));
        local bouncer=".oO°Oo.";
        for ((i=0;i<loca;i++)); do
                t="${bouncer:((i%${#bouncer})):1}"
                bgcolor="\\E[${bgcolors[RANDOM % 14]}m \\033[m"
                y+="$bgcolor";
        done
        fgcolor="\\E[${fgcolors[RANDOM % 14]}m"
        echo -ne " $fgcolor$t$y$z$fgcolor$t \\E[96m(\\E[36m$w%\\E[96m)\\E[92m $fgcolor$loca2\\033[m\r"
};
timeprogress() {
        local loca="$1"; local loca2="$2";
        loca=$(bc -l <<< scale=2\;"$loca/50")
        for i in {1..50}; do
                progressbar "$i" "$loca2";
                sleep "$loca";
        done
        echo -e "\n"
};
timeprogress "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: Please don't hard-code terminal-specific control codes - make friends with `tput` instead.

Comment: I redid the script using tput as you suggest. The speed was terribly reduced. Not a good suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I still see control codes, and no `tput` usage.  I'd be very surprised if it was noticeably slower to call it a handful of times (to initialise suitable variables), but it would possibly be noticeable if one were to invoke it anew every time the control code were needed.