# Kill dbus monitor script when application exits?

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, dbus

I am using a simple dbus-monitor script for gnote. The script starts when gnote starts. I modified `exec` parameter of desktop file to achieve this.

The problem is that I didn't find any way to kill my script after the application(i.e **gnote**) exits. If the application itself exits there is no point to keep script running in the background as it is not going to fetch any output.

The script looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash 


OJECT="'org.gnome.Gnote'" 
IFACE="'org.gnome.Gnote.RemoteControl'" 
DPATH="'/org/gnome/Gnote/RemoteControl'" 
echo $IFACE


WATCH1="type='signal',sender=${OJECT},interface=${IFACE},path=${DPATH},member='NoteAdded'" 
WATCH2="type='signal',sender=${OJECT},interface=${IFACE},path=${DPATH},member='NoteSaved'" 
WATCH3="type='signal', sender=${OJECT}, interface=${IFACE}, path=${DPATH}, member='NoteDeleted'"

dbus-monitor ${WATCH2} | 
while read LINE; do
  echo $LINE | grep "note://"
done
```

I tried to modify it like this :

```sh
dbus-monitor ${WATCH2} | 
while read LINE; do
  echo $LINE | grep "note://"
  if pgrep "gnote" > /dev/null; then
    echo ""
  else
    break;
  fi
done

pid=`pidof -x $(basename $0)`
kill $pid
```

But it didn't work. I also tried using `trap` as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165057/executing-bash-loop-while-command-is-running) but without success.

Comment: Answered in askubuntu. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911969/kill-dbus-monitor-script-when-application-exits

Comment: Oops! http://askubuntu.com/questions/821806/