# Display a progress bar or spinner while a command is running in bash script

Tags: bash, progress-bar

I have a bash script that ends as follows:

```
trap "exit" INT
for ((i=0; i < $srccount; i++)); do
    echo -e "\"${src[$i]}\" will be synchronized to \"${dest[$i]}\""
    echo -e $'Press any key to continue or Ctrl+C to exit...\n' 
    read -rs -n1
    #show_progress_bar()
    rsync ${opt1} ${opt2} ${opt3} ${src[$i]} ${dest[$i]}
done
```

I need a command or a function such as `show_progress_bar()` that put `.` (a dot) in the stdout every one second while `rsync` command is running (or a rotating `/` that rotates as `/ - \ |` sequence while `rsync` is running).
Is it possible? Do I need to wrote such function myself, or there is available scripts for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but it works:

```
~$ while true; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done & sleep 3; kill %-; wait; echo;
[1] 26255
...[1]+  Terminated              while true; do
    echo -n .; sleep 1;
done
```

(exchange the "sleep 3" for your actual work)

It works like this:

- The while loop runs as a background job.
- Meanwhile, your work ("sleep 3" in my example) runs in the foreground.
- When the work is done, "kill %-" kills the echo loop.
- Then we wait for the job to terminate, and echo a newline, just in case.

Like I said, it's not pretty. And there's probably a much better way to do it. :)

*EDIT:* For example, like the answer here: [Using BASH to display a progress (working) indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498304/using-bash-to-display-a-progress-working-indicator)