# Print a period while waiting for a command to finish

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a script that takes about 10 mins to run. I want to print something to the terminal to give a visual indicator that something is happening. The original command is as follows:

```
stats:
        $(MAKE) add > last_output.txt 2> err.txt
```

It waits for the Makefile target "add" to return and sends the output to last_output.txt and then doesn't print out the errors to the terminal.

I don't have much experience with Makefiles and shell scripting but, after googling I have come up with a line like this:

```
stats:
        @until $(MAKE) $* > last_output.txt 2> err.txt; do echo -n "." ; done
```

It doesn't print anything out. But what I want to happen is while the original script is waiting to return the output look like:

```
$ make stats
.
..
...
....
.....
<results of target "stats">
```

I can't add a progress bar to the original script because I cannot edit it. Since I can't add a progress bar I figured something like this would still do a similar job. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `until` command doesn't work like that. Instead it runs a command repeatedly until it returns a succesful status.

I.e. `until` is a command repeater, not a "wait for completion" expression.

However if you are willing to use an external tool, then with something like [`pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) you could print progress updates as long as there is output from the `make` command.

```
$(MAKE) add 2> err.txt | pv -t -p -i 0.1 -w 40 > last_output.txt
```

This will print a small left-right animating bar with a ticking timer like so:

```
0:00:08 [    <=>                       ]
```

You can test it on the command line yourself with something like this:

```
while true; do date; sleep 0.1; done | pv -t -p -i 0.1 -w 40 > /dev/null
```

If you want a more bash-oriented solution, you can try to look at this question with perhaps some answers that would fit your requirements:
[Using Bash to display a progress indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498304/using-bash-to-display-a-progress-indicator)

Comment: Reminder that GNU Make default shell is `sh`, not `bash`, for anyone going for the linked Bash alternative.

Comment: @Casper, That sounds like a fantastic idea! Unfortunately, I don't have permission on the system to install packages. In regards to the Bash progress indicators, since I am calling the command from a Makefile I'm not sure how to merge a Makefile and Bash.