# Show garbage data on console in unix

Tags: unix

My shell script iterates on a text file to process another file. This takes around 2 minutes to finish. By the time this script finishes its task I want to print some random data on console to entertain user. How can I do this.

My code is:

```
while read line
do
        origVal=`echo $line | awk '{ printf $1 }'`
        newVal=`echo $line | awk '{ printf $2 }'`
        sed "s/$origVal/$newVal/g" File > tmpFile
        mv tmpFile File
done < ConfigFile.txt
```

Comment: You can run your process in background using `&`.

Comment: I assume you meant you want a progress bar for the user to look at while the program runs. Check this previous question out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script

Add echo -ne with \r to overwrite the previous stdout and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the command "fortune" at the end of your script. Like so:

```
fortune
```

It will print random data to entertain the user.