# How to add progress bar to a somearchive.tar.xz extract

Tags: bash, tar

I'd like to print at the very least print # files extracted, from running a tarball extract

```
xz -dc /path/to/somearchive.tar.xz | sudo tar xvpf - -C /path/to/some_directory
```

I was thinking of using the "\r" as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073), for instance

```
num=0
when [\n received]
    num=$(($num + 1))
    echo -ne "$num files extracted \r"
end when
```

my bash skills fail me.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

#### Using `pv` to pipe the file to `tar`.

1. Firstly, you'll need to install `pv`, which on macOS can be done with:

   ```bash
   brew install pv
   ```

   *On Debian or Ubuntu, it can be done with: `apt install pv`* (Thanks [@hyperbola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8386446/hyperbola)!).
2. Pipe the compressed file with `pv` to the `tar` command:

   ```bash
   pv mysql.tar.gz | tar -xz
   ```

Here's the sample output of this command:

[image: Sample output]

For those curious, this works by `pv` knowing the total file size of the file you pass it and how much of it has been "piped" to the `tar` command. It uses those two things to determine the current progress, the average speed, and the estimated completion time. Neat!

Comment: `pv "$SOURCE_FILE" | xz -0 --stdout > "$TARGET_FILE"`, in case someone is trying to 'zip' using `xz`. Yes, it's the opposite of what OP is doing, but that's what _I_ was looking for :)

Comment: Can it be done with additional `-v` parameter for `tar`?

Comment: For debian or ubuntu users, `pv` can be installed by `apt install pv`.

Comment: @hyperbola Thank you for adding that. I've added it to the answer as well.

Answer (score 48):

When extracting with `tar` you can use the [`--checkpoint`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/verbose.html) option. What you get is not really a progress bar but good enough to see the progress.

In this example, `tar` will print a message each 100 records written. If you place a dot immediately after the equal sign, it will just print a `.`.

```
tar -xf somearchive.tar.gz --checkpoint=.100
```

Output:

```
.......
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, simple yet useful +1.

Comment: This just shows `...` without its 100% percent

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on centos release 8 with gnu tar v1.30. What works on gnu tar is: `tar xvnf archive.tgz --checkpoint=1000 --checkpoint-action=dot`. This was introduced in [v1.20](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/NEWS#n781)

Comment: Per @royarisse's answer, we can make tar to print 1 dot for roughly 1% by adjusting the checkpoint size, e.g. in bash `tar -xf somearchive.tar.gz --checkpoint=$(($(stat -c %s somearchive.tar.gz)/512/20/100)) --checkpoint-action=.`

Answer (score 14):

If you really want to do it by file you could use:

```
tar xvpf /path/to/archive.tar.xz -C /path/to/dir 2>&1 | 
while read line; do
    x=$((x+1))
    echo -en "$x extracted\r"
done
```

Notes:

- You probably don't need to `xz` separately, most `tar` implementations will automatically detect and decompress it for you.
- `tar` reads from stdin by default, you don't need `f -`.

You should look into using [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) instead, it's more precise and more generally applicable:

```
pv /path/to/archive.tar.xz | tar xp -C /path/to/dir
```

Comment: You forgot `xzcat` in your `pv` sample: `pv /path/to/archive.tar.xz | xzcat | sudo tar -xpC /path/to/dir`

Comment: Nice answer, didn't know that `tar` output could be sequentially piped like that

Comment: @F.Hauri no I'm not, see my note about `tar` automatically detecting compression.

Comment: @h3nr1x Yep, it's basically designed like any other command line utility, for pipelines. It just happens to normally take and output binary data.

Comment: With `pv`, then, per file: `lines=$(tar -tJf archive.txz | wc -l); tar -xvpf archive.txz 2>&1 | pv -ls$lines`

Comment: this: ```pv /path/to/archive.tar.xz | sudo tar xp -C /path/to/dir``` how could I make it an alias, so I could write something like: ```progtar inputfile destination/dir```

Comment: Just *do* it. Don't **sudo** it all the time

Comment: I also apply whiptail: 

local x=0
tar -xvf "$archive" -C "$TEMPORARY_DIRECTORY" |
while read line; do
    x=$((x+1))
    echo $x
done | whiptail --title "Установка" --gauge "Распаковка архива" 6 60 $x

Answer (score 6):

While the `pv` solution shows progress nicely, it doesn't show what files are extracted whereto. The `--checkpoint=.100` option shows the files and indicates that it's working, but doesn't show progress.

On the [Tar Checkpoints](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_26.html) page I found some information about the `--checkpoint-action` option, which is able to execute some bash magic for every checkpoint. Knowing that a checkpoint is created every 20 blocks of 512 bytes (at least that's the default, see `man tar`), It's possible to get the progress based on the current block and the original size.

The snippet below can be saved as a bash file (or put into a bash function):

```
archive="$1"

originalsize=$(file $archive | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev)
step=100
blocks=$(echo "$originalsize / 512 / 20 / $step" | bc)

tar -xvz --checkpoint=$step --totals \
 --checkpoint-action="exec='p=\$(echo "\$TAR_CHECKPOINT/$blocks" | bc -l);printf \"%.4f%%\r\" \$p'" \
 -f $archive
```

Then using it is very straightforward:

```
bash tarprogress.sh your.archive.tgz
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with xz files like this:

```
unxz -v --stdout file.tar.xz | tar -x
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also [progress](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress), which you could use like this:

```
tar xp -C /path/to/dir & progress -mp $!
```

Or even:

```
watch progress -q
```