# PHP shell script 'echo -ne' how? (Shell Progressbar)

Tags: php, shell, echo, command-line-interface, shell-exec

I have a PHP script where I want to show its progess.
From this super question and perfect answer [How to add a progress bar to a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script) I tried to emulate the behaviour:

```
shell_exec("echo -ne '######      30%'\r");
```

But nothing gets printed to the screen.

My guess is this is because STDOUT not correct, or I have to echo the echo like?

```
echo shell_exec("echo -ne '######      30%'\r");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use this in a php shell script you don't need to execute any shell commands at all. Just echo the output ending with a `\r`

```
echo "######      30%\r";
```

example script:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i += 5) {
  $bar = str_repeat("#", $i/10);
  echo "$i% $bar \r";
  sleep(1);
}
echo "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Change `$i <= 100` or else the script will end in 95% i guess

Comment: doesn't really matter, it's just an example

Comment: I was curious weather the PHP echo works because I cannot set the `-ne` from the system's echo. I should have tried.. =)

Comment: You could have looked up what `-ne` does. The bash echo command always adds `\n` at the end. `-n` ommits the trailing newline. `-e` enables the interpretion of backslash escapes. Without it the `\r` would have no effect. The PHP echo needs none of these options.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example for a progress bar in PHP command line interface: http://brian.moonspot.net/php-progress-bar

It is directly done in PHP without system calls.