# How do I watch the progress when doing searching or find in Unix/CMD

Tags: bash, unix

Is there any functional keyword which able to display the progress in percentage when I do "find" or "grep" command? For example, when I do "wget" command, I can see the percentage when downloading.

Comment: You could pipe through a progessbar like [bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script) or [Pipe viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml), but what are the 100% of find? related Question:   
http://serverfault.com/questions/341143/linux-find-command-show-progress

Comment: A percentage with `wget` makes sense: there is a known number of bytes coming, and you can count how many of them have arrived so far. What would you display for `find` and `grep`?

Comment: Because I want to let client know how much source has gone through within the directory, therefore client does not need to guess. sometimes it just hanging on searching. So I decided to show progress bar, meanwhile list the matched files. For example, virus scanning application is the one.

Comment: @taymedee In order to do that, you would have to run the search twice - once to find out how big the haystack is so that you can calculate percentages on the second run, and then a second time to do your actual search, displaying progress as you go. So, say your search takes 10 minutes - your user would wait 10 minutes before seeing that you are starting at 0%, and another 10 minutes to get to 100%. I suspect this is not really what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the great [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) ("pipe viewer") which you can inject into a pipe to monitor progress.

However, as @chepner points out there is probably little point in using it with `find` or `grep` since you have no size to relate to.