# Update Xcode build progress bar when using run script

Tags: xcode, build

In Xcode you can specify custom scripts to build your applications. I have a project which makes extensive use of these. For instance, one target builds the simulator versions (both 32bit and 64bit) and the ARM version as well as documentation and then bundles up the generated static library into a framework along with some other files

Running the above code can take a couple of minutes. Normally when you build, Xcode has a progress bar at the top of the screen. When you use these scripts it fills in a tiny amount and then stops there until your script completes.

It would be nice if there was a way to tell Xcode to update this progress bar? It doesn't have to be perfect, just a way of giving some feedback that something is happening and that the build process hasn't stalled.

Thanks!

Comment: Having this would be great when running the resource build scripts for my game. Any progress on this?

Comment: Not a thing unfortunately. I took to just building from the command line instead.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like [you can use Bash](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaRunScriptBuildPhase.html) in your custom build script.  So why not do something like in the example linked, wherein for each build target you do

```
echo "building target name blare"
```

In fact, if you really want a progress bar, why not just use Bash to make one?  See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/238094/1586231).

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for the feedback in the top bar of xcode. Otherwise I could just look at the output of the build scripts (where there are much better ways of doing progress bars).

Comment: Yeah, I know I didn't answer the explicit question.  There are better ways of doing progress bars out there, but I didn't want to suggest a particular library over something generic like this.  And I'm fairly certain what you want to do cannot be done.