# Pipe-view a loop sequence (add a progress bar to While or For loop) - Bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, pipe, progress-bar, viewer

As posted [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/343197/grep-progress-bar-using-pv-pipe-viewer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script), pipeviewer is a tool that shows content progress based on it's size. As seen there, the proposal of their questions is to get a progress bar of a process running without data volume.

I was wondering if is it possible to show progress of a loop with pipeviewer, considering that I'm reading it from a file, and I know it's size.

I've trying something like

`while IFS= read -r line;
 do
   <code>
 done < file.txt | pv`

And this definitelly doesn't work, since pv shows only an empty progress bar.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, read the file with `pv` instead of `cat`, so that pv will automatically get the file size and format the progress bar appropriately.

For example:

```
pv very_big_file.txt
```

or, in your example:

```
pv file.txt | while IFS= read -r line;
do
    <code>
done
```

---

If you cannot read the file with `pv`, you can pass `pv` the size of the file with `-s size`.
That way, `pv` will expect the flow to be that length, and format the progress bar proportionally to it.

You can get the size of a file with:

```
stat -c '%s' file
```

or

```
wc -c < file
```

For example:

```
command1 | command2 | ... | pv -s $(stat -c '%s' file) | commandX | ...
```

in your example:

```
cat file.txt | pv -s $(stat -c '%s' file.txt) | while IFS= read -r line;
do
    <code>
done
```

As you see, it is redundant to use `pv` just after cat, it should be substituted by a `pv` reading the file.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean... Thank you, sir! I'll figure out a way to hide the first empty bar that PV adds unintentionally, but your simple but functional solution is more than appreciated!

Comment: for  me this shows a progress bar for the read operation only, before any work is done inside the loop, presumably because the file is read as buffered

any way to actually cause read to consume it line by line?