# Spinner in Shell

Tags: shell, terminal, posix, sh

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3330834/4557537) for BASH, but I want to do the same thing with shell (`#!/bin/sh`).

The twist is to make it a timer also, so like wait 60 seconds for example until it ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fadi's own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38252213/45375) is helpful (and comes by courtesy of [Adam Katz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519360/adam-katz) comment on the linked answer), but comes with 2 caveats:

- The spinner, due to using `\r`, only works at the *beginning* of a line.
- Per POSIX, `sleep` only supports *integral* seconds.

It may also not be readily obvious where to test for whether the operation is done and how to exit the two loops vs. how to use a spinner as a *background* job, while waiting for a blocking command to finish.

The following snippets address these issues; they use `\b` (backspace) rather than `\r`, which allows the spinner to be displayed with preceding text, if desired:

---

**Asynchronous case (poll for completion)**:

If you're waiting for completion of a process *asynchronously* (by checking for completion *periodically*, in a loop):

```
printf 'Processing: '
while :; do
  for c in / - \\ \|; do # Loop over the sequence of spinner chars.
    # Print next spinner char.
    printf '%s\b' "$c"
    # Perform your custom test to see if the operation is done here.
    # In this example we wait for a file named 'results' to appear.
    # Note that `[ -f results ] && ...` is just a shorter alternative to
    # `if [ -f results]; then ... fi`.
    [ -f results ] && { printf '\n'; break 2; } # Print a newline, break out of both loops.
    sleep 1 # Sleep, then continue the loop.
  done
done
```

The above, due to printing the `\b` char. *after* the spinner char., displays the cursor *behind* the spinner char; if that is aesthetically undesirable, use the following variation to **display the cursor *on top* of the spinner**:

```
printf 'Processing:  ' # note the extra space, which will be erased in the first iteration
while :; do
  for c in / - \\ \|; do
    printf '\b%s' "$c" 
    [ -f results ] && { printf '\n'; break 2; }
    sleep 1
  done
done
```

[I0_ol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5904552/i0-ol) suggests using `tput civis` and `tput cnorm` to ***hide* the cursor temporarily**; while not strictly POSIX-compliant (POSIX mandates only 3 `tput` operands: `clear`, `init`, and `reset`), it does appear to be supported by most modern terminal emulators.

```
printf 'Processing: '
tput civis # Hide cursor.
# To be safe, ensure that the cursor is turned back on when
# the script terminates, for whatever reason.
trap 'tput cnorm' EXIT
while :; do
  for c in / - \\ \|; do
    printf '%s\b' "$c" 
    [ -f results ] && { printf '\n'; break 2; }
    sleep 1
  done
done
tput cnorm # Show cursor again.
```

A more complete example **with configurable timeout and sleep interval** (note that the timeout enforcement will not be exact, as the time it takes to process each loop iteration is not taken into account; in `bash`, you could simply reset special var. `SECONDS` before the loop starts and then check its value):

```
# Determine how long to sleep in each iteration
# and when to timeout (integral seconds).
sleepInterval=1 timeout=10 elapsed=0 timedOut=0

printf 'Processing:  ' # note the extra space, which will be erased in the first iteration
while :; do
  for c in / - \\ \|; do
    printf '\b%s' "$c" 
    [ -f results ] && { printf '\nDone.\n'; break 2; }
    [ $elapsed -ge $timeout ] && { timedOut=1; printf '\nTIMED OUT\n' >&2; break 2; }
    sleep $sleepInterval
    elapsed=$(( elapsed + sleepInterval ))
  done
done
```

---

**Synchronous (blocking) case**:

If you're waiting for a lengthy synchronous (blocking) command to complete, the spinner must be launched as a *background job*, which you then terminate once the blocking call has completed.

```
printf 'Processing: '
# Start the spinner in the background.
# The background job's PID is stored in special variable `$!`.
(while :; do for c in / - \\ \|; do printf '%s\b' "$c"; sleep 1; done; done) &

# Run the synchronous (blocking) command.
# In this example we simply sleep for a few seconds.
sleep 3

# The blocking command has finished:
# Print a newline and kill the spinner job.
{ printf '\n'; kill $! && wait $!; } 2>/dev/null

echo Done.
```

Comment: I love your blocking case. I may actually use this. Thanks!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is this:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0
while [ $i -le 60 ]; do
  for s in / - \\ \|; do
    printf "\r$s"
    sleep .1
  done
  i=$((i+1))
done
```