# how can i show pop up with the help of shell scripting?

Tags: shell, scripting, popup, progress-bar

In order to track progress of particular process. I want to show progress bar with percentage of completion of process.
Please advise, is it possible to use pop-up to show progress bar like windows or pop-up with specific message.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a progress bar to a shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script)

Comment: @Fazlin, I want to know about showing pop-up using shell scripting..It is not necessary to show progress bar..if pop up is possible then we can also able to show any specific text with pop-up.

Comment: @Fazlin,..regarding your suggested question.. this question is only related about progress bar..by using sleep cmd.and that progress bar is not related to actual running process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two simple tools for the purpose:

1. The tool `zenity` allows to create GUI progress bar from shell script, e.g. `zenity --progress --auto-close`. The `zenity` is often preinstalled on many Linux systems. The tool starts, and shows the GUI progress bar, while on stdin it expects percentage of completion. E.g.:

   ```
   seq 0 20 100 | while read X; do sleep 1; echo $X; done |
      zenity --progress --auto-close
   ```
2. The `pv` tool ("Pipe Viewer") can be used as a replacement for the `cat` but with the perk that it shows a progress bar in text mode indicating the amount/speed of data passing through the `pv`. One has to install it, as normally it is not preinstalled. For example, to add progress bar to decompression of large archive:

   ```
   pv large.tar.bz2 | tar -xjf -
   ```