# Making simple shell progress bar

Tags: bash, shell, progress-bar, progressdialog

I may be very bad at implementing the progress bars mentioned here: [How to add a progress bar to a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script). But I would very much like a progress bar for a shell install script I am making. It could (in terms of looks) be similar to this,

```
'[                           (00%)]/'
'[#####                      (33%)]\'
'[##################         (66%)]-'
'[##########################(100%)]|'
```

where we have a progress bar, a percentage counter and a spinning device. I would very much like for it to be modular so that I can use in other projects too but perhaps I then ask for something which is too complicated. I do not know how and what it should count, but I thought that it would be somewhat smart to simply count the number of lines executed in my script and compare this number to the total number of lines, but I am of course open for other suggestions.

Comment: Lines take a varying amount of time to execute. It should be based on the expected time left.

Comment: I know. But right now I would just like some sort of script. If you know how to make an estimate of how much time is left I would very much enjoy seeing such a solution! :-) My problem is, however, that the script I am doing right know does a lot of apt-gets, downloads from GitHub and installing various .deb files, so I do not know how I should have a clue myself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a progress bar, % counter & spinner :

```
#!/bin/bash

spin() {
    sp='/-\|'
    printf ' '
    while true; do
        printf '\b%.1s' "$sp"
        sp=${sp#?}${sp%???}
        sleep 0.05
    done
}

progressbar()
{
    bar="##################################################"
    barlength=${#bar}
    n=$(($1*barlength/100))
    printf "\r[%-${barlength}s (%d%%)] " "${bar:0:n}" "$1" 
}

spin &
pid=$!

#your task here

for i in `seq 1 100`;
do
    progressbar $i
    sleep 0.1
done

# kill the spinner task
kill $pid > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Spinner is started at the beginning and stopped at the end, the progress bar function is called each time % change.

You can customize progress bar style updating `"\r[%-${barlength}s (%d%%)] "` format

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Sadly, I cannot get it to work, though. I am trying to make the following install.sh file have a progress bar. :-/
https://github.com/mstaal/i3buntu

Comment: The for loop is an example. Call progress bar function with specified % value each time you want to change the %. The moment when you want to change the % is up to your actions to be processed in your script.

Comment: I now think I understand your point. But I get a syntax error when loading the script. It says that (for some reason) there should not be a left parenthesis when loading the spin function.

Comment: I have removed `function` statement, it should be working fine with this